# Prevent memory leaks in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks, angular, rxjs

In Angular 2 are there any specific pitfalls regarding memory management, I should be aware of?

What are the best practices to manage the state of components in order to avoid possible leaks?

Specifically, I've seen some people [unsubscribing from HTTP observables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34402906/352796) in the `ngOnDestroy` method. Should I always do that?

In Angular 1.X I know that when a `$scope` is destroyed, all listeners on it are destroyed as well, automatically. What about observables in Angular 2 components?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'library',
  template: `
    <tr *ngFor="#book of books | async">
        <td>{{ book.title.text }}</td>
        <td>{{ book.author.text }}</td>
    </tr>
  `
})
export class Library {
    books: Observable<any>;

    constructor(private backend: Backend) {
        this.books = this.backend.get('/texts'); // <-- does it get destroyed
                                                 //     with the component?
    }
};
```

Comment: don't forget to unsubscribe from Observable in ngOnDestroy

Comment: In your case unsubscribing from the Observable in `ngOnDestroy` is not necessary, the `Async` pipe handle all that for you. That would be a *good practice*, instead of subscribing yourself let the pipe do that everything for you.

Comment: @EricMartinez, thanks! I would accept that as the answer (especially if you provide a proof link).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it necessary to unsubscribe from observables created by Http methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042929/is-it-necessary-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-created-by-http-methods)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As requested by @katspaugh

In your specific case there's no need to unsubscribe manually since that's the Async pipe's job.

Check the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/common/pipes/async_pipe.ts#L73-L77) for AsyncPipe. For brevity I'm posting the relevant code

```js
class AsyncPipe implements PipeTransform, OnDestroy {
    // ...
    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        if (isPresent(this._subscription)) {
          this._dispose();
        }
    }
```

As you can see the Async pipe implements OnDestroy, and when it's destroyed it checks if is there some subscription and removes it.

You would be reinventing the wheel in this specific case (sorry for repeating myself). This doesn't mean you can't/shouldn't unsubscribe yourself in any other case like the one you referenced. In that case the user is passing the Observable between components to communicate them so it's good practice to unsubscribe manually.

I'm not aware of if the framework can detect any *alive* subscriptions and unsubscribe of them automatically when Components are destroyed, that would require more investigation of course.

I hope this clarifies a little about Async pipe.

Comment: Hey @katspaugh I got an answer from Rob and I thought you could be interested on it, check it out here in this [comment](https://gitter.im/angular/angular?at=5681e8ce3c68940269251f9f)

Comment: Check out this [hangout talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UHI0AzD_WfY) as well (min 27:40), it doesn't go deep on the subject, but I was curious about it because of your question and found out that video.

Comment: Thanks, interesting! So Rob basically says you don't need to unsubscribe from observables that complete with a single value (HTTP requests being an example of those).

Answer (score 4):

You do not have to unsubscribe from standard subscriptions like after http.get(). 
But you DO have to unsubscribe from subscription on your custom Subjects. If you have some component and inside it you subscribing to some Subject in your service, then every time you showing that component new subscription will be added to the Subject.

[image: Problems with my service]

Please check this out: [Good solution to make your components 'clean'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription)

My personal approach - all my components are extended from this nice class:

```html
import { OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

/**
 * A component that cleans all subscriptions with oneself
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription
 * @class NeatComponent
 */
export abstract class NeatComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
// Add '.takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)' before every '.subscrybe(...)'
// and this subscriptions will be cleaned up on component destroy.

  protected ngUnsubscribe: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  public ngOnDestroy() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
  }

  public ngOnInit(){}
}
```

And I just adding **super()** call to constructor and **.takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)** before every subscribe:

```html
import { NeatComponent } from '../../types/neat.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'category-selector',
  templateUrl: './category-selector.component.pug'
})
export class CategorySelectorComponent extends NeatComponent {

  public constructor(
    private _shopService: ShopsService
  ) { super(); }

  public ngOnInit() {
    this._shopService.categories.takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
      .subscribe((categories: any) => {
        // your code here
      })
  }
}
```