# Is it necessary to unsubscribe from observables created by Http methods to avoid memory leaks?

Tags: angular, memory-leaks, rxjs, angular2-http

Do you need to unsubscribe from Angular 2 http calls to prevent memory leak?

```
 fetchFilm(index) {
        var sub = this._http.get(`http://example.com`)
            .map(result => result.json())
            .map(json => {
                dispatch(this.receiveFilm(json));
            })
            .subscribe(e=>sub.unsubscribe());
            ...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent memory leaks in Angular 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34461842/prevent-memory-leaks-in-angular-2)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34461842/prevent-memory-leaks-in-angular-2 (and the comments as well)

Comment: If your reading this question, be wary of the accepted answer (which the OP wrote themselves). If you read the [other answers they ALL refute that you don't have to unsubscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51850733/542251). Just because it has the most upvotes and is accepted, does not make it correct.

Comment: @Liam The OP question was "to prevent memory leaks".  The top answer is correct.  No.  There are other considerations on why you might or might not want to unsubscribe that the other answers address.

Answer (score 362):

So the answer is no, you don't. `Ng2` will clean it up itself.

The Http service source, from Angular's Http XHR backend source:

[image]

Notice how it runs the `complete()` after getting the result. This means it actually unsubscribes on completion. So you don't need to do it yourself.

Here is a test to validate:

```
  fetchFilms() {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(this.requestFilms());

        let observer = this._http.get(`${BASE_URL}`)
            .map(result => result.json())
            .map(json => {
                dispatch(this.receiveFilms(json.results));
                dispatch(this.receiveNumberOfFilms(json.count));
                console.log("2 isUnsubscribed",observer.isUnsubscribed);
                window.setTimeout(() => {
                  console.log("3 isUnsubscribed",observer.isUnsubscribed);
                },10);
            })
            .subscribe();
        console.log("1 isUnsubscribed",observer.isUnsubscribed);
    };
}
```

As expected, you can see that it is always unsubscribed automatically after getting the result and finishing with the observable operators. This happens on a timeout (#3) so we can check the status of the observable when it's all done and completed.

And the result

[image]

So, no leak would exist as `Ng2` auto unsubscribes!

Nice to mention: This `Observable` is categorized as `finite`, on contrary to the `infinite` `Observable`which is an infinite stream of data can be emitted like DOM `click` listener for example.

THANKS, @rubyboy for help on this.

Comment: what happens in the cases where the user leaves the page before the response comes in, or if the response never comes before the user leaves the view? Would that not cause a leak?

Comment: @1984 The answer is ALWAYS UNSUBSCRIBE. This answer is entirely wrong for exactly the reason brought up in this comment. The user navigating away is a memory link. Plus, if the code in that subscribe runs after the user navigates away it could cause errors / have unexpected side effects. I tend to use takeWhile(()=>this.componentActive) on all observables and just set this.componentActive=false in ngOnDestroy to clean up all observables in a component.

Comment: Yes, but the question refers to HTTP calls, and I believe the http client module handles unsubscribing from observables?

Comment: The example displayed here covers a deep angular private api. with any other private api, it can change with an upgrade with no notice. Rule of thumb is: If it's not officially documented, don't make any assumptions.
Per example, the AsynPipe has clear documentation that it automatically subscribe/unsubscribe for you. The HttpClient docs do not mention anything about that.

Comment: @YoussefTaghlabi, FYI, the official angular documentation (https://angular.io/guide/http) does mention that: "The AsyncPipe subscribes (and unsubscribes) for you automatically." So, it's indeed officially documented.

Comment: @Lenny I saw a lot of such recommendations even for http requests. But I don't understand how subscribed Observable from http request can cause a memory leak. As I understand XmlHttpRequest is held by browser only during awaiting server response. After response is received, XmlHttpRequest and Observable became detached from stack and therefore became subjects to garbage collection. So why should we care about memory leaks? P.S. I understand that this has nothing to do with executing response callback on destroyed component.

Comment: @Hudgi, what you are talking about is when you use the async pipe ... but this is when you use the observable directly in the html template. For instance: obsrvbl$ | async

Comment: The class handling XHR can be found here, if anyone is curious: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/xsrf.ts

Answer (score 218):

##### What are you people talking about!!!

OK so there's two reasons to unsubscribe from any observable. Nobody seems to be talking much about the very important second reason!

> 1. Clean up resources. As others have said this is a negligible problem for HTTP observables. It'll just clean itself up.

> 2. Prevent the `subscribe` handler from being run.

Note that with an HTTP observable, when you unsubscribe it will cancel the underlying request in your browser for you (you'll see 'Cancelled' in red in Network panel). This means time won't be wasted downloading or parsing the response. But that's actually an aside to my main point below.

The relevance of number 2 is going to depend upon what your subscribe handler does:

> If your `subscribe()` handler function has any kind of side effect that is undesired
> if whatever calls it is closed or disposed then you must unsubscribe (or add conditional logic) to prevent it from being executed.

Consider a few cases:

1. A login form. You enter username and password and click 'Login'. What if the server is slow and you decide to hit Escape to close the dialog? You'll probably assume you weren't logged in, but if the http request returned after you hit escape then then you will still execute whatever logic you have there. This may result in a redirect to an account page, an unwanted login cookie or token variable being set. This is probably not what your user expected.
2. A 'send email' form.

If the `subscribe` handler for 'sendEmail' does something like trigger a 'Your email is sent' animation, transfer you to a different page or tries to access anything that has been disposed you may get exceptions or unwanted behavior.

Also be careful not to assume `unsubscribe()` means 'cancel'. Once the HTTP message is in-flight `unsubscribe()` will NOT cancel the HTTP request if it's already reached your server. It will only cancel the response coming back to you. And the email will probably get sent.

If you create the subscription to send the email directly inside a UI component then you probably would want to unsubscribe on dispose, but if the email is being sent by a non-UI centralized service then you probably wouldn't need to.

3. An Angular component that is destroyed / closed. Any http observables still running at the time will complete and run their logic unless you unsubscribe in `onDestroy()`. Whether the consequences are trivial or not will depend upon what you do in the subscribe handler. If you try to update something that doesn't exist anymore you may get an error.

Sometimes you may have some actions you would want if the component is disposed, and some you wouldn't. For example maybe you have a 'swoosh' sound for a sent email. You'd probably want this to play even if the component was closed, but if you try to run an animation on the component it would fail. In that case some extra conditional logic inside subscribe would be the solution - and you would NOT want to unsubscribe the http observable.

So in answer to the actual question, no you don't need to do it to avoid memory leaks. But you need to do it (often) to avoid unwanted side effects being triggered by running code that may throw exceptions or corrupt your application state.

Tip: The `Subscription` contains a `closed` boolean property that may be useful in advanced cases. For HTTP this will be set when it completes. In Angular it might be useful in some situations to set a `_isDestroyed` property in `ngDestroy` which can be checked by your `subscribe` handler.

Tip 2: If handling multiple subscriptions you can create an ad-hoc `new Subscription()` object and `add(...)` any other subscriptions to it - so when you unsubscribe from the main one it will unsubscribe all the added subscriptions too.

Comment: Also note that if you have a service that returns the raw http overvable and you then pipe it before subscribing then you only need to unsubscribe from the final observable, not the underlying http observable. In fact you won't even have a Subscription to http directly so you can't.

Comment: Even though unsubscribing cancels the browser request, the server still acts on the request. Is there a way to intimate the server to abort the operation too? I'm sending out http requests in quick succession, of which most are cancelled by unsubscribing. But, server still operates on the requests cancelled by the client, causing the legitimate request to wait.

Comment: @bala you'd have to come up with your own mechanism for this - which wouldn't have anything to do with RxJS. For instance you may just put the requests into a table and run them after 5 seconds in the background, then if something needed to be cancelled you would just delete or set a flag on the older rows that would stop them executing. Would entirely depend upon what your application is. However since you mention the server is blocking it may be configured to only allow one request at a time - but that again would depend on what you were using.

Comment: Tip 2 - is a PRO-TIP,  for anyone who wants to unsubscribe from multiple subscription by calling just one function. Add by using .add() method and than .unsubscribe() in ngDestroy.

Comment:  For those coming to this in 2022 and beyond, an even more PRO-TIP is to use Net Basal's https://github.com/ngneat/until-destroy package. You can thank me later 

Answer (score 72):

**Unsubscribing** is a **MUST** if you want a **deterministic** behavior on all network speeds.

**Imagine** that component A is rendered in a tab - You click a button to send a 'GET' request out. It takes 200 ms for the response to come back. So, you are safe to close the tab at any moment knowing that, the machine will be faster than you & the http response is processed and is complete before the tab is closed and component A is destroyed.

**How about on a very slow network?** You click a button, the 'GET' request takes 10 seconds to receive its response, but 5 seconds into waiting you decide to close the tab. That will destroy component A to be garbage-collected at a later time.  **Wait a minute!**, we did not unsubscribe -- **now** 5 seconds later, a response comes back and the logic in the destroyed component will be executed. That execution is now considered `out-of-context` and can result in many things including very low performance and data/state corruption.

So, the best practice is to use `takeUntil()` and unsubscribe from http call subscriptions when the component is destroyed.

**Note:**

- RxJS is not Angular specific
- Angular `async` pipe used in templates unsubscribes on destroy automatically
- Unsubscribing more than once has no negative side effect, except the extra `no-op` calls

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

interface User {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-foobar',
  templateUrl: './foobar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./foobar.component.scss'],
})
export class FoobarComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private user: User = null;
  private destroy$ = new Subject();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http
      .get<User>('api/user/id')
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe(user => {
        this.user = user;
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next();  // trigger the unsubscribe
    this.destroy$.complete(); // finalize & clean up the subject stream
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it okay to use `BehaviorSubject()` instead and call just `complete()` in `ngOnDestroy()`?

Comment: You would still need to unsubscribe... why would `BehaviourSubject` be different?

Comment: There is no need to unsubscribe from HttpClient observables as they are finite observables, i.e. they complete after emitting a value.

Comment: You should unsubscribe anyway, suppose there is an interceptor to toast errors, but you've already left the page that triggered the error.. you will see a error message in another page.... Also think about a health-check page that calls all microservices... and so on

Comment: Where is the "unsubscribe" behavior in the provided example?

Comment: @Saksham Please use Subject() as we only care about the future emit due to calling `next()` in our ngOnDestroy().  BehaviorSubject() emits it current value triggering an unsubscribe() right away.

Comment: @YatharthVarshney I encourage that you read the scenario I described one more time prior to making any final decisions. Deterministic software is a result of deterministic execution paths.

Comment: @JosephGabriel the `unsubscribe` is happening via `takeUntil(this.destroy$)` and that is triggered from within the `ngOnDestory` by calling `this.destroy$.next();` which is automatic when the component or service is destroyed.

Comment: try async pipe too :D, it's recommended way for automatic subscription and unsubcription

Comment: Make it into muscle memory - Every place in a `.ts` file you see a `.subscribe()`, make sure there is a deliberate unsubscribe for it.  Even if `take(n)`, `first()`, etc. are used.  A single `out-of-context` execution can send a team of experts wonder around for weeks!

Comment: The best way to don't forget to unsubscribe is to never subscribe in the .ts. Use pipe async provide by Angular in the .html. In this example you can change user in Observable of user. In the OnInit you can affect the result of http call in user$ and dont subscribe because you'll do it in the .html with pipe async ! You dont need to unsubscribe in the .ts now !!

Answer (score 32):

After a while of testing, reading documentation and the sourcecode of the HttpClient.

`HttpClient:` https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/client.ts

`HttpXhrBackend :` https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/xhr.ts

`HttpClientModule`: https://indepth.dev/exploring-the-httpclientmodule-in-angular/

Angular Univeristy: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-http/

> This particular type of Observables are single-value streams: If the HTTP request is successful, these observables will emit only one value and then complete

And the answer to the whole Issue of "do i NEED" to unsubscribe ?

**It depends.** 
Http call Memoryleaks are not a issue. 
The issues are the logic in your callback functions.

For example: Routing or Login.

If your call is a login call, you don't have to "unsubscribe" but you need to make sure if the User leaves the page, you handle the response properly in the absence of the user.

```js
this.authorisationService
      .authorize(data.username, data.password)
      .subscribe((res: HttpResponse<object>) => {
          this.handleLoginResponse(res);
        },
        (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          this.messageService.error('Authentication failed');
        },
        () => {
          this.messageService.info('Login has completed');
        })
```

**From annoying to dangerous**

Now just imagine, the network is slower than usual, the call takes longer 5 seconds, and the user leaves the login view and goes to a "support view" .

The component may not be active but the subscription. In case of a response, the user will be suddenly rerouted (depending on your handleResponse() implementation).

This is **not** good.

Also just imagine the user leaves the pc, believing he is not logged in yet. But you logic logs the user in, now you have a security issue.

**What can you do WITHOUT unsubscribing?**

Make you call dependent on the current state of the view:

```js
  public isActive = false;
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isActive = true;
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.isActive = false;
  }
```

User `.pipe(takeWhile(value => this.isActive))` to make sure the response is only handled when the view is active.

```js
this.authorisationService
      .authorize(data.username, data.password).pipe(takeWhile(value => this.isActive))
      .subscribe((res: HttpResponse<object>) => {
          this.handleLoginResponse(res);
        },
        (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          this.messageService.error('Authentication failed');
        },
        () => {
          this.messageService.info('Login has completed');
        })
```

**But how can you be sure that the subscription isn't causing memoryleaks ?**

You can log if the "teardownLogic" is applied.

The teardownLogic of a subscription will be called when the subcription is empty or unsubscribed.

```js
this.authorisationService
      .authorize(data.username, data.password).pipe(takeWhile(value => this.isActive))
      .subscribe((res: HttpResponse<object>) => {
          this.handleLoginResponse(res);
        },
        (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          this.messageService.error('Authentication failed');
        },
        () => {
          this.messageService.info('Login has completed');
    }).add(() => {
        // this is the teardown function
        // will be called in the end
      this.messageService.info('Teardown');
    });
```

You don't have to unsubscribe.
You should know if there are issues in your logic, that could cause Problems in your subscription. And take care of them. In the most cases, it won't be a issue, but especcialy at critical tasks like autorization, you should take care of unexpected behaviour, wether its with "unsubscribe" or a other logic like piping or conditional callback functions.

**why not just always unsubscribe?**

Imagine you make a put or post request. The server recieves the message either way, just the response takes a while. Unsubscribing, won't undo the post or put. 
But when you unsubscribe, you won't have the chance to handle the response or inform the User, for example via Dialog or a Toast/Message etc.

Wich causes the User to believe, that the put/post request was not done.

So it depends. It is your design decision, how to deal with such issues.

Answer (score 28):

Calling the `unsubscribe` method is rather to cancel an in-progress HTTP request since this method calls the `abort` one on the underlying XHR object and remove listeners on the load and error events:

```
// From the XHRConnection class
return () => {
  _xhr.removeEventListener('load', onLoad);
  _xhr.removeEventListener('error', onError);
  _xhr.abort();
};
```

That said, `unsubscribe` removes listeners... So it could be a good idea but I don't think that it's necessary for a single request ;-)

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: :| that's absurd :| i was looking for a way to stop... but i was wonder, and if it was me coding, in some scenario: i would do it like this: `y = x.subscribe((x)=>data = x); ` then a user change in inputs and `x.subscribe((x)=>cachlist[n] = x); y.unsubscribe()` hey you used our server resources, i won't throw you away ..... and in other scenario: just call `y.stop()` throw everything away

Comment: Thierry Templier, thanks for you suggestion, but let say in a case, i have to make 10 API call on loading of page but i navigate to another page before data gets loaded then it will be very useful (the unsubscription will cancel all the API calls, which is great in performance)

Answer (score 14):

Also with the new HttpClient module, remains the same behaviour 
[image: packages/common/http/src/jsonp.ts]

Comment: The above code seems to be from a unit test, implying that with HttpClient, you DO need to call .complete() on your own (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4c2ce4e8ba4c5ac5ce8754d67bc6603eaad4564a/packages/common/http/testing/src/request.ts)

Comment: Yes, you're right, but if you inspect (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4c2ce4e8ba4c5ac5ce8754d67bc6603eaad4564a/packages/common/http/src/jsonp.ts#L159) you will see the same.

Regarding the main question, if necessary to explicitly unsubscribe? most of the cases no, since is gonna be handled by Angular itself. Could be a case in which a long response could take place and you've moved to another route or maybe destroyed a component, in which case you have the possibility of try to access something that doesn't exist anymore raising an exception.

Answer (score 13):

You should definitely read [this](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/why-you-have-to-unsubscribe-from-observable-92502d5639d0) article. It shows you why you should **always unsubscribe even from http**.

> If after creating the request but before receiving an answer from the
> back-end you deem the component unnecessary and destroy it, your
> subscription will maintain the reference to the component thus
> creating a chance for causing memory leaks.

**Update**

The above affirmation seems to be true, but anyway, when  the answer comes back the http subscription is destroyed anyway

Comment: Yes and you’ll actually see a red ‘cancel’ in your browser’s network tab so you can be sure it works.

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: @robert Yes, seems to be broken now.

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't unsubscribe from observables that completes automatically (e.g Http, calls). But it's necessary to unsubscribe from infinite observables like `Observable.timer()`.

Answer (score 1):

A good part that could help understand this is that an HTTP request isn't made unless there is a call to the subscribe function. Though the answers on this page seem to suggest two different practices, it really doesn't makes much of a
difference as the required behavior would be controlled by an async pipe, as indicated by the angular [docs](https://angular.io/guide/http) (though it's mentioned much later in the section 'Making a DELETE request'):

The AsyncPipe subscribes (and unsubscribes) for you automatically.

In fact, it's even harder to find any example in docs where such observables are explicitly unsubscribed by calling the unsubscribe function.

Answer (score -2):

RxJS observable are basically associated and work accordingly you subscribe it. When we create the observable and the movement we complete it, observable automatically gets closed and unsubscribed.

They work in the same fashion of the watchers but quite different order.
The better practice to unsubscribe them when component is getting destroy.We could subsequently do that by **eg. this.$manageSubscription.unsubscibe()**

If we have created the observable like below mentioned syntax such as

**
**return new Observable((observer) => {
** // It makes observable in cold state
** observer.complete() 
**})**
**

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is necessary to unsubscribe.

Due to [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http-request-data-from-server#starting-the-request):

> You should always unsubscribe from an observable when a component is destroyed.

Comment: Non applicable on HttpClient methods, they are cold by design and unsubscribe automatically after response or timeout