# How to make a put request in angular2 using http?

Tags: typescript, angular

I am working on this angular2 application and I am doing CRUD operations.

I have http for making `get` & `post` requests.

I want to perform `put` operation now but cannot find anything relevant.

Any inputs?

Thanks.

Comment: this.http.put() ? Does not work?

Comment: it works,but i want to know the syntax & parameters to do that?

Comment: It has exactly the same syntax with POST https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/http/src/http.ts

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you are already familiar with `POST`, then

Only difference between POST and PUT request is literally `UT` instead of `OST`,
it's just a `verb`, for front-end atleast.

[Angular Docs (have to make it complicated)](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html#!#sts=Put)

```
// Update existing Hero
private put(hero: Hero) {
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  let url = `${this.heroesUrl}/${hero.id}`;

  return this.http
             .put(url, JSON.stringify(hero), {headers: headers})
             .map(res => res.json());
}
```

---

**And remember** - Observables can be lazy (eg: Angular's `Http` request) so you need to subscribe on them to make the request execute even if you don't want to handle the response. – ***@user2171669***

Comment: you need to return JSON string from your service to make `res.json()` work, if not returning anything then you don't need `.map(res => res.json());`

Comment: @Ankit Singh Observables are lazy so you need to subscribe on them to make the request execute even if you don't want to handle the response.

Comment: @user2171669 You should have your comment as an answer!

Comment: Why do they `JSON.stringify()` the body? Is that necessary/best practice?

Comment: With version 4 you don't have to JSON.stringify() in fact that can create an error. Just add the object to the body and Angular does the rest.

Comment: also, if someone is asking itself about, they do not subscribe itself _but_ does UNsubscribe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35043309/2079428

Answer (score 1):

```
    //For .map(res => res.json()); 
    //solution is below.. 
       private updateProduct(product: IProduct, options: RequestOptions):     Observable  {
       const url = `${this.baseUrl}/${product.id}`;
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        return this._http.put(url, JSON.stringify(product), {headers: headers})
               .map(() => product)
               .do(data => console.log('updateProduct: ' + JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data || null)) ))   
            .catch(this.handleError);
       } 
    //But I am unable to update any record....
```