# Angular2: Do we need to cancel the subscriptions to a service when it gets destroyed?

Tags: angular, typescript

Do we need to cancel our subscriptions to a service when it gets destroyed ?

Based on the destroy event, other components that were listenning to this service can cancel their subscriptions. I just don't see why is it important to do so.

Is this a good practise, or a necessity for a performance purpose ?

Comment: Did not you get the answer from this http://stackoverflow.com/q/35042929/744534

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you do, because stuff like this can cause memory leaks. It's always a good practice to clean up after yourself to ensure that you don't run into big problems down the road, as I have in the past, especially with Angular 1.

Cleaning up after your subscriptions are fairly straightforward:

```
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';
```

In your class:

```
public configSubscription: Subscription;
```

Inside constructor or `ngOnInit` or other appropriate place:

```
this.configSubscription = this.api.config$.subscribe(
  config => {
    this.config = config;
});
```

Then clean up with this:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.configSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: @Scipion In that case I don't think you need to worry.  Once you cast to a promise, the underlying Observable will complete as soon as the promise resolves/rejects.  This is because promises by definition only emit a single value, so their resources don't linger as is the case with Observables. PS: Maybe someone else can weigh in here, but there is one edge case: if your Promise takes forever to resolve b/c the source Observable doesn't emit, that resource is still alive.  In that case you may need to address it, but I still don't see the danger of memleak unless you keep spanning promises