# Angular: Issue in adding dynamically generated input field data on the (change) event

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-in-memory-web-api

I have a feature where I need to send dynamically generated input fields on button click.

I have recreated the problem on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-fields) for better understanding.

In that app, when I enter resourceQuantity, the resourceId fields are dynamically generated. 
My issue is to identify those fields individually and send them on server side on single button click.

[This](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-form-fields) solution I've found on stackblitz is similar, but in my problem I am not removing or adding on button clicks, but (change) event instead.

Here is the **HTML** code:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input  matInput type="number" formControlName="resourceQuantity" [(ngModel)]="resourceQuantity" placeholder="Enter Resource Quantity" (change)="somethingChanged()"/> 
</mat-form-field><br/><br/>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of counter(resourceQuantity)">
            <input  matInput type="number" placeholder="Enter Resource Number" formControlName="resourceId"/> 
        </li>       
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here is the **TS** code:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
            'employeeId': new FormControl(null, {validators: [Validators.required]}),
            'employeeName': new FormControl(null, {validators: [Validators.required]}),
            'resourceQuantity': new FormControl(null, {validators: [Validators.required]}),
            'resourceId': new FormControl(null, {validators: [Validators.required]})
    });
  }

  somethingChanged() {
      console.log(this.resourceQuantity);
  }

  counter(i: number) {
      return new Array(i);
  }
```

Kindly let me know the best solution to my problem. Thanks.

Comment: You mean to say you want something like this: {empId:1, empName:"abc", resourceQuantity:2, resourceId:11, resourceId:22} ? @Rachit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid using `ngModel` and `formControl` together. You can make use of `formArray` along with getter functions in your component to get your result.

**Edit**: I have edited my code to reflect the change you requested by subscribing to `valueChanges` on the `resourceQuantity` `formControl` and generating the `formArray` when it detects the change. This creates the resources in real time.

**Note**: Don't forget to [unsubscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41364078/angular-2-does-subscribing-to-formcontrols-valuechanges-need-an-unsubscribe) from `valueChanges` to prevent memory leakage. I have updated my Stackblitz to show the same.

Here is a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dyanmic-fields-form-array)

Comment: Thanks @nash11, it works but the input fields are not generating if I click the top and down arrows of matInput.

Comment: Check out the stackblitz again. I have edited my code :)

Comment: Thank you so much, Nash! Also, I didn't try the array approach because the resourceIds are supposed to be unique at DB level. So, I have made a separate table to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is a perfect use case for `formArray`... the only difference is that you need to add the formControls on the basis on the value which is entered in the `resourceQuantity` field.

relevant **HTML**:

```
<mat-card>
    <form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="add()">
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput type="number" formControlName="employeeId" placeholder="Enter Employee Id" (change)='updateFormString()'/>
      </mat-form-field><br/><br/>
      <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput formControlName="employeeName" placeholder="Enter Employee Name" (change)='updateFormString()'/>
      </mat-form-field><br/><br/>
      <mat-form-field>
            <input  matInput type="number" formControlName="resourceQuantity" [(ngModel)]="resourceQuantity" placeholder="Enter Resource Quantity" (change)="somethingChanged()"/> 
        </mat-form-field><br/><br/>
           <!--
             <div>
                <ul>
                    <li *ngFor="let item of counter(resourceQuantity)">
                        <input  matInput type="number" placeholder="Enter Resource Number" formControlName="resourceId"/> 
                    </li>       
                </ul>
            </div>
            -->
        <div fxLayout>
            <div>
                <button
                    mat-raised-button
                    color="accent" [disabled] = "form.invalid">Save
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div formArrayName='resourceId'>
          <br/>
          <div *ngFor='let item of resourceId.controls; let i = index'>
            <input type='text' [formControlName]="i" >
          </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</mat-card>

{{formString}}
```

relevant **TS**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormArray, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
  resourceQuantity: any;
  formString: string;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      'employeeId': new FormControl(null, { validators: [Validators.required] }),
      'employeeName': new FormControl(null, { validators: [Validators.required] }),
      'resourceQuantity': new FormControl(null, { validators: [Validators.required] }),
      //'resourceId': new FormControl(null, {validators: [Validators.required]}),
      resourceId: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.control('test entry default')
      ])
    });
  }

  updateFormString() {
    this.formString = JSON.stringify(this.form.value);
  }

  somethingChanged() {
    for (var i = 1; i < this.resourceQuantity; i++) {
      this.addResource();
    }
    this.updateFormString();
  }

  get resourceId() {
    return this.form.get('resourceId') as FormArray;
  }

  addResource() {
    this.resourceId.push(this.fb.control('test entry additional'));
  }

  counter(i: number) {
    return new Array(i);
  }
}
```

working [stackblitz available here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-fields-hyqmrc)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `FormArray` to solve this issue. [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-fields-n8vaim)

1.Change your `resourceId` from `FormControl` to `FormArray` as Follows.

```
 'resourceId': new FormArray([])
```

2.Change your `counter` method to push `FormControl` in your `FormArray` based on the **Resource Quantity**, this method calls when the change event triggers in the **Resource Quantity**. It gets the `resourceQuantity` value from the `FormGroup`, then clears the `FormArray` value. After that, it loops over the index to dynamically create `FormControl` and push it in `FormArray`

```
counter() {
    const index = parseInt(this.form.value.resourceQuantity);
    (this.form.controls.resourceId as FormArray).clear();
    for(let i = 0; i < index; i++) {
      const formControl = new FormControl();
      (this.form.controls.resourceId as FormArray).push(formControl);
    }
}
```

3.use getters to access the controls easily

```
  get formControls(): any {
    return this.form.controls;
  }

  get resourceIDControls(): any {
    return this.form.controls.resourceId['controls'];
  }
```

4.Change your HTML to loop over `FormArray` and set the `FormControlName` dynamically.

```
<div formArrayName="resourceId">
     <ul>
         <li *ngFor="let item of resourceIDControls; let i = index">
             <input  matInput type="number" placeholder="Enter Resource Number" [formControlName]="i"/> 
         </li>       
     </ul>
 </div>
```

[image: Sample Inputs - Demo]

[image: Form Value after the submission will look like this]

Comment: Thanks @Bear. It doesn't work real time if I enter the text. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: what do you mean by real time?, do you want to add form controls on keypress of resource quantity?

Comment: Yes! As I type/retype the value, the number of input fields should change accordingly.

Comment: just change the event from `(change)="counter()"` to `(keypress)="counter()"`

Answer (score 1):

I would also set up my employee model to include a Resource array;

```
import { Resource } from './resource.model';

export interface Employee {
    employeeId: number;
    employeeName: string;
    resourceQuantity: number;
    resourceIds: Resource[];
}
```

Then your resource just needs a id:

```
export interface Resource {
    resourceId: number;
}
```