# Angular: Problem in adding data from one component using two services

Tags: json, angular, rest, service, sequelize.js

This question is related to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56896608/angular-issue-in-adding-dynamically-generated-input-field-data-on-the-change). The issue I'm facing is in sending the data to back-end using two services.

I have read about using forkJoin of Observables but I am not able to use it for my problem.

My **add()** method:

```
add() {
    this.employeesService
    .createEmployee(this.form.value as Employee)
    .subscribe(
        employee=> {
            console.log(employee);
        },
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            this.messagesService.openDialog('Error', 'Invalid Employee. Try Again!');
        }
    );
    const resources: any = {};
    const employeeId: any = {};
    let wholeData: any = [];
    function makeArray(resourceNumber, id) {
        resources.push(resourceNumber);
        for(var i = 0; i < this.resourceNumber.length; i++) {
            employeeId.push(id);
        }
    }
    wholeData = new makeArray(this.resourceNumbers, employeeId);
    this.resourceNumbersService
    .createResourceNumber(wholeData as Resource)
    .subscribe(
        resourceNumber => {
            console.log(resourceNumber);
        },
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            this.messagesService.openDialog('Error', 'Invalid Resource Number. Try Again!');
        }
    );
}
```

This is the Postman Json format for resources which is doing well with my backend:

```
{ "resources": [ { "resourceNumber": "121", "employeeId": "3" }, 
{ "resourceNumber": "122",  "employeeId": "3" }, 
{ "resourceNumber": "123", "employeeId": "3"} ] }
```

The trouble I'm facing is in sending the data to resources database. The Employees are sent totally fine. Is there any easier approach? Many thanks.
Kindly find the problem on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-observable-forkjoin-example)

Answer (score 0):

> I have read about using forkJoin of Observables but I am not able to
>   use it for my problem.

So following is the way to use `forkJoin`

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';  // RxJS 6 syntax


  functionReturningForkJoinOFObservableBatch(): Observable<any[]> {
    let observableBatch = [];
    observableBatch.push("push all observables ")
    return forkJoin(...observableBatch);
  }

   //subscribe the above function to get response of all observable in single go

   //When all observables complete, emit the values

     this.functionReturningForkJoinOFObservableBatch().subscribe(responseList => {
        });
```

Comment: Hey @Amrit I am not getting a good idea of how to implement that code in my problem. Could you please check my updated question and have a look into the stackblitz problem...