# Angular 10 : Should I unsubscribe form subscription to valueChanges Observable in ngOnDestroy?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular10

I have a form like this :

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  username: ["Put name"],
  address: ["Put address"]
});
```

And I am listening to username input value :

```
this.form.controls.username.valueChanges.subscribe(val =>
 //doSomething()
);
```

Do you think I should add a **pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))** in order to avoid memory leaks ?

Is there a way to test if I do not unsubscribe when the component is destroyed, the Observable is still living in memory ?

Comment: Yes, you always should unsubscribe from your subscriptions. You can do it with pipe or just with Subscription property with usage the unsubscribe method in ngOnDestroy hook.

Comment: To make sure you don't have any memory leaks - yes. It's a best practice.

Comment: Its the best practise. just implement OnDestroy and add a Subscription field. Also do the unsubscription inside the ngOnDestroy() method.\

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41364078/angular-2-does-subscribing-to-formcontrols-valuechanges-need-an-unsubscribe/46893278
answers this question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 - Does subscribing to FormControl's valueChanges need an unsubscribe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41364078/angular-2-does-subscribing-to-formcontrols-valuechanges-need-an-unsubscribe)

Comment: Is there a way to test if I do not unsubscribe when the component is destroyed, the Observable is still living in memory ?

Comment: You **don't have to unsubscribe** in this case. That Subject(`valueChanges`) is bound to that component and when that component is destroyed, there is no way the subscribers will ever receive any values. [Here](https://indepth.dev/posts/1433/rxjs-why-memory-leaks-occur-when-using-a-subject) you can find an article that explains why memory leaks occur.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of destroy, you could also do this

```
public sub: Subscription;

contructor() {
  this.sub = new Subscription();
}

this.sub.add(this.form.controls.username.valueChanges.subscribe(val =>
 //doSomething()
));

ngOnDestroy() {
   this.sub.unsubscribe();
}
```