# is there an equivalent of async pipe that you can use inside a component?

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

Does there exist something equivalent to the `async` pipe that I could use inside a component like this

```
   @Component({
      selector: 'my-component',
    })

    export class myComponent {

      myObservable$: Observable<string>;

      method() {
        doSomething(this.myObservable$);
        // here I would like to access directly the current string value of
        // myObservable$ without having to subscribe 
      }
    }
```

Comment: Could you maybe describe the case a little? Because usually there is no real need for this, any data-transformation should be writable as a stream.

Answer (score 6):

You have to ask yourself: What do you want to achieve by avoiding the `subscribe()` call? My guess is that you want to prevent keeping the subscription around and having to unsubscribe manually.

If this is the case, you just have to make sure you get an Observable that completes. Then there is no need to unsubscribe later. You can convert any Observable (finite or infinite) to one that will eventually complete.

Here is an example for your case:

```
  method() {
    this.myObservable$.take(1).subscribe(
      val => doSomething(val)
    );
  }
```

The correct way really depends on what your observable does and what you want to do with the value. Angular2 http calls for example complete on their own, [no need to unsubscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042929/do-you-need-to-unsubscribe-from-angular-2-http-calls-to-prevent-memory-leak)!

Or if you want to call doSomething for every new value in your observable, the above solution won't fit because you only get the first value, then the observable completes. As I said, this comes down to the context of the problem.

Comment: thanks for you suggestion, but let say in a case, i have to make 10 API call on loading of page but i navigate to another page before data gets loaded then it will be very useful (the unsubscription will cancel all the API calls, which is great in performance)

Answer (score 4):

No there's not. You need to **manually subscribe and manually unsubscribe** to avoid memory leaks.

For a simple subscription you may be tempted to do :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
})
export class myComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public myObservable$: Observable<string>;
  private myObservableSub: Subscription;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myObservableSub = this
      .myObservable$
      .subscribe(_ => {
        // do something
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.myObservableSub();
  }
}
```

But what if you have many subscribe ?
Should you do something like :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
})
export class myComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public myObservable1$: Observable<string>;
  private myObservableSub1: Subscription;

  public myObservable2$: Observable<string>;
  private myObservableSub2: Subscription;

  public myObservable3$: Observable<string>;
  private myObservableSub3: Subscription;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myObservableSub1 = this
      .myObservable1$
      .subscribe(_ => {
        // do something
      });

    this.myObservableSub2 = this
      .myObservable2$
      .subscribe(_ => {
        // do something
      });

    this.myObservableSub3 = this
      .myObservable3$
      .subscribe(_ => {
        // do something
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.myObservableSub1();
    this.myObservableSub2();
    this.myObservableSub3();
  }
}
```

---

**THE ANSWER IS NO**

---

***Upadted reply (16/11/20)***

In the original answer *(see after this edit)*, I do avise to use take until but this forces you to create a subject and trigger an event into it when the component is destroyed. While the idea behind this is good, it's quite a lot of boilerplate to put in all the components where we subscribe to a stream.

Instead of this, we can create a custom operator that we can call `takeUntilDestroyed` and do something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
})
export class myComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public myObservable1$: Observable<string>; // define your observable

  public myObservable2$: Observable<string>; // define your observable

  public myObservable3$: Observable<string>; // define your observable

  ngOnInit() {
    this
      .myObservable1$
      .pipe(takeUntilDestroyed(this))
      .subscribe(_ => {
        // do something
      });

    this.myObservableSub2 = this
      .myObservable2$
      .pipe(takeUntilDestroyed(this))
      .subscribe(_ => {
        // do something
      });

    this.myObservableSub3 = this
      .myObservable3$
      .pipe(takeUntilDestroyed(this))
      .subscribe(_ => {
        // do something
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {}
}
```

The implementation of this custom operator can be found here: https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-sub-form/blob/1115b21a007f72c54b521b3bed7c40051302145a/projects/ngx-sub-form/src/lib/shared/ngx-sub-form-utils.ts#L145-L148

***Original reply***

**You should rather do the following :**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
})
export class myComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private componentDestroyed$ = new Subject<void>();

  public myObservable1$: Observable<string>;
  public myObservable2$: Observable<string>;
  public myObservable3$: Observable<string>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this
      .myObservable1$
      .takeUntil(componentDestroyed$)
      .subscribe(_ => {
        // do something
      });

    this
      .myObservable2$
      .takeUntil(componentDestroyed$)
      .subscribe(_ => {
        // do something
      });

    this
      .myObservable3$
      .takeUntil(componentDestroyed$)
      .subscribe(_ => {
        // do something
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.componentDestroyed$.next();
    this.componentDestroyed$.complete();
  }
}
```

If you want to know more about that, here's an excellent article from *Ben Lesh* : https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87

**EDIT :**
Thanks to @olsn, I edited my answer and added the line with the `next` because indeed a complete doesn't stop the others streams.

I created a small Plunkr to demo that behaviour : https://plnkr.co/edit/dcueDqUgpqgYimxEAGUn?p=preview

Comment: Your `this.componentDestroyed$.complete()` will not stop any of the streams, you need to call `.next()` since `complete` will just finalize the stream, but not emit any data that other streams can react to.

Comment: @olsn thanks, I edited the post and quoted your answer !

Comment: The example of takeUntil resolved the issues I was having that led me to this question.

Answer (score 2):

If you're in a `Component` or something which has access to a `ChangeDetectorRef`, you can do the following little trick:

```
@Component({
...
  providers: [AsyncPipe]
})
export class ExampleComponent {
  app$ = this.sandbox.allApps$;
  apps = this.pipeAsync.transform(this.app$);

  contructor(
    protected pipeAsync: AsyncPipe,
    protected sandbox: AppAppsSandbox
  ) {}
}
```

This assumes access to a service called `AppAppsSandbox`, but the `Observable` `app$` can come from anywhere, this is a convenient way to unwrap it.

Comment: This is really cool but leads to race conditions, at least in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Answering 5 years late, but technically 'kind of'. You could always do something like:

```
import { firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

...

async method(){
   let mySingleValue = await firstValueFrom(this.myObservable$);
   doSomething(mySingleValue);
   // keep accessing mySingleValue directly here
}
```

Which solves your problem, but it's not very clean and requires an async function. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

The only way you can your goal (not using subscription) is to use BehaviorSubject, it has a method getValue(). There are some differences between Observables and BehaviousSubjects (you can find them in [documentation](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md)).

```
var subject = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(current_subject_value);
subject.getValue()
```

Yet there are some stackoverflow debates why shoudnd't you use getValue method, but rather to use subscription... Yet there is observable take operator which will complete observable sequence (thus don't have to manage subscriptions)

```
this.myObservable$.take(1).subscribe()
```