# Angular - specify observable return type?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have this part in a function :

```
this.myservice.getComments()
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.post.comments = data.body;
    this.post.comments_count = Number(data.headers.get('x-wp-total'));
    this.post.comments_pages = Number(data.headers.get('x-wp-totalpages'));
    this.content_ready = true;
  });
```

The `getComments` function :

```
export class myservice extends DataService {
  protected url = 'my_url';

  constructor( protected http: HttpClient ) {
    super(http);
  }

  getComments(){
    return this.get(
      this.subUrl, true );
  }
}
```

Relevant part of dataService :

```
export class DataService {
  protected url: string;

  constructor(protected http: HttpClient) {}

  get(subUrl:string = '', needObservable = false) {
    let options = {};
    if(needObservable) {
      options = {observe: 'response'};
    }
    return this.http.get(this.url + subUrl, options);
  }
}
```

All of this works well. The thing is, my IDE (phpstorm) is complaining about the `data.headers` and `data.body`, arguing that those properties does not exists on type 'object'.

How to let it know that everything is fine ? I thought about typing the return but not succeeding in doing so.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The type of your `data` should be the type that is returned from your `http.get<T>()`

```
get(subUrl:string = '', needObservable = false) : Observable<T> {
    let options = {};
    if(needObservable) {
      options = {observe: 'response'};
    }
    return this.http.get<T>(this.url + subUrl, options); // add a type that you are expecting to be returned from api
}
```

-subscription

```
this.myservice.getComments()
  .subscribe((data : T) => {
    this.post.comments = data.body;
    this.post.comments_count = Number(data.headers.get('x-wp-total'));
    this.post.comments_pages = Number(data.headers.get('x-wp-totalpages'));
    this.content_ready = true;
});
```

Answer (score 6):

This is not related to the IDE. Just Typescript's compiler is arguing that type `object` does not has those properties and it is right.

Just set the type of `data` to `any` - `data: any`.

```
.subscribe((data: any) => {
    this.post.comments = data.body;
    this.post.comments_count = Number(data.headers.get('x-wp-total'));
    this.post.comments_pages = Number(data.headers.get('x-wp-totalpages'));
    this.content_ready = true;
});
```

Comment: Seems right. Typing should be in parenthesis ! Thanks.

Comment: The return type must know You, I can't. Any is just a workaround

Answer (score 1):

Its a good practise to know the type of returned data... This is how you assign it https://stackoverflow.com/a/49627627/9590251

In your case - create an interface and assign returned data to type