# Why map doesn't work after upgrading RxJS to v6.3

Tags: typescript, type-conversion, rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have a similar case to one described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49627239/casting-a-type-interface-via-map-to-observable).

I have a user login service, which (among other things) verifies if user's token is still valid. The server's response is defined in an interface:

```js
export interface UserVerifyResponse {
    success: boolean
}
```

My aim was to create an observable that will return a boolean value depending on whether user is verified. This code was working with RxJS v6.2:

```
authenticate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.get<boolean>(
        this.apiUrl+'/verify_user'
    ).pipe(
        map<UserVerifyResponse, boolean>((receivedData: UserVerifyResponse) => {
            return receivedData.success;
        }),
        tap((data: boolean) => {console.log("User authenticated", data)}),
        catchError(this.handleError)
    )
}
```

However, now that I have updated RxJS to v6.3 I get this error:

```
ERROR in src/app/login/user.service.ts(50,13): error TS2345: Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<UserVerifyResponse, boolean>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<boolean, boolean>'.
  Type 'UserVerifyResponse' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

It bothers me, because I use this approach of mapping API response to an internal class or a primitive (in other place I have a service which uses `http.get<T>`) and now I wonder if I should force RxJS 6.2 or there is an easy way to migrate to 6.3. I can rewrite all of them as it is described in the answer to the above mentioned post, but I I want to return a boolean value and my approach looks clearer in my opinion.

Any suggestions?

Comment: By this `this.http.get<boolean>` you're saying that this request will return an Observable emitting `boolean`s. But then you use `map<UserVerifyResponse, boolean>` where `UserVerifyResponse` is an object instead of `boolean`.

Comment: Because this is what I want the request to return. With RxJS v6.2 I was able to translate the response that I received from the API (of type `UserVerifyResponse`) to `boolean`, so finally the `http.get` would return Observable of type `boolean`. Why was it acceptable previously and now it is wrong logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, they have improved the type-checking.

When you wrote `this.http.get<boolean>`, you are saying "this get is returning an Observable of type boolean", which is *not* what you mean.  The get is returning an Observable of type `UserVerifyResponse` and you should say so:

```
authenticate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.get<UserVerifyResponse>(
        this.apiUrl+'/verify_user'
    ).pipe(
        map((receivedData) => {
            return receivedData.success;
        }),
        tap((data) => {console.log("User authenticated", data)}),
        catchError(this.handleError)
    )
}
```

The pipe alters the Observable from  `UserVerifyResponse` to the `boolean` that is ultimately returned.

Note that I have deleted most of the typing you had.  In general, you should only specify type when:

- you have to, as is the case with the `get()` itself, since the TypeScript compiler cannot correctly infer the type, *or*
- you are writing a publicly available function, as is the case with `authenticate()`, since while TypeScript can infer the type, someone reading your code later probably cannot.