# Getting data requires two subcriptions

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am asking this question for learning purposes. Here is my service:

```
export class HomeService {
   private generalstatistics = new ReplaySubject<object>();
   constructor(
   private http: HttpClient
     ) {
    this.data();
  }
  public get generalStatistics(): Observable<object> {
    return this.generalstatistics.asObservable();
  }
  data() {
    this.http.get<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/home/`)
    subscribe(data => {
    this.generalstatistics.next(data);
  });
 }
}
```

Here I have my first subscription. Then somewhere in a component that needs that data I have the following:

```
constructor(private dataSvc: HomeService) {
  this.getData();
}
getData() {
   this.dataSvc.generalStatistics
   .subscribe(data => {
   this.source = data;
 });
}
```

Which has my second subscription. So just for the learning purpose, is it possible to avoid two subscriptions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should instead of doing a subscription inside the service do this inside the component.

Eg.:

```
data() {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/home/`)
});
```

and accordingly do your subscription of this wherever you need it!

Inside a component e.g.:

```
this.homeservice.data().subscribe(...)
```

if you do this you will reduce complexity and have less code duplicates.

Hope it helps!

Comment: VS code says Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '() => Observable<any>'

Comment: I guess you need to cast it properly, have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49627239/casting-a-type-interface-via-map-to-observable :)

`getRestaurant() {
  this.restaurantProvider.getRestaurant().subscribe((res: restaurant) => {
    this.restaurant = res;
  });
}`

Adding the type should resolve your issue - and will make your app more typesafe

Comment: I am changing my service to be like this: data(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/home/`)
    .map((response: any) => response.data as any); Error: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'

Comment: You need to `pipe` the `map` operator. You can't just stick them on the end since RxJS 6