# How to get if http request aborted in Angular 2?

Tags: ajax, angular, http

I use a loading bar plugin to show user if there is an http request. But sometimes, user clicks for a new route (I use angular's routing) and (I guess) http request automatically aborted by angular. Therefore I can't know I should stop the loading bar.

How can I handle this?

P.S.: I handle all http request in a service file.

Comment: Provide relevant code or plunker.

Comment: ``.unsubscribe()`` will stop the http request .

Comment: @CruelEngine I know that, I am asking how to get if a request is unsubscribed?

Comment: ``.isUnsubscribed`` will return ``false`` if the http request is unsubscribed @Sam

Comment: @Sam you can refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042929/do-you-need-to-unsubscribe-from-angular-2-http-calls-to-prevent-memory-leak