# Do we need to unsubscribe from http calls in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Probably a silly question, but couldn't find an answer easily.

In an Angular application where I'm using `Rxjs` to make `http` calls to get and post data to a server. Let's say I have a service `MyService` with a method like this:

```
getData() {
  this.http
      .get("mybackendurl/mydata")
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => this.data = data);
}
```

So, let's say I use this method in a couple places and a every time I navigate into a page.
Regardless of the convenience of doing it this way, my question is, this is not like a Promise, that starts and finishes, as far as I know this keeps a connection open until the source terminates, so do I need to somehow unsubscribe from this every time I finish the request?

As the subscription is done in a service and not in a component, the service won't be destroyed, hence I fear I might be creating multiple subscriptions and connections instead of reusing the same one.

Thanks!

Comment: Be aware of your cold/hot Observables (https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339). A hot one can fire multiple times e.g. a Subject that you call .next() on. Other ones like the http call give you a cold Observable which completes (or fails) just once.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For Http request you don't need to unsubscribe. It actually ***completes*** the observable, so you will ***not have any memory leaks***.

You can check this by using `add` function of the `Subscription` object. This function is called when Subscription is unsubscribed. Also you can check via passing the `complete` function (the 3rd parameter) into the `subscribe` function, which will be called after the request and will mean that observable is completed.

```
this.http
    .get("mybackendurl/mydata")
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => this.data = data)
    .add(() => console.log('Unsubscribed'));
```

Comment: Be sure to check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51850733/2080346