# HTTP Request Unsubscribe doesn't work

Tags: angular, typescript, subscribe, reactivex

I'm fetching the data from `json` file in services and subscribing it from my component. I'm doing some condition check with the data, once it matches I want to stop subscribing but it's not working and still its subscribing.

**Service**

```angular
getUserData() {
     const url = './assets/json/userslist.json';
     return this.http.get(url);
}
```

**Component**

```
const subscription = this.getuser.getUserData().subscribe(data => {
  Object.values(data).forEach((userdetail) => {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
    if (userdetail.username.indexOf(form.value.email) !== -1 && userdetail.password == form.value.password) {
      console.log('asd');
      if (userdetail.active == true) {
        console.log('asasdfasd');
        this.EventEmitterObj.emit(form.value.email);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
      } else if (userdetail.active == false) {
        console.log('asd23423432');
        this.deactivateAlert = 'The account is deactivated';
      }
      subscription.unsubscribe();
      console.log('issue');
    } else {
      console.log('12341243');
      this.deactivateAlert = 'Incorrect Username/Password';
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: why are you `subscription.unsubscribe();` in forEach?

Comment: By the time you get your json from the http call the observable has completed. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48516432/do-we-need-to-unsubscribe-from-http-calls-in-angular and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042929/is-it-necessary-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-created-by-http-methods

Comment: There is no need to unsubscribe .it will be automatically unsubscribe on request completion.

Answer (score 2):

### Angular HTTPClient

The angular `HTTPClient` will `unsubscribe` automatically on request completion.
That is either *on success* or *on error*.

Also at the time you are unsubscribing, the http request is already returned a `success` so it is *completed*.

What i am understanding from your code is that, you are expecting the `unsubscribe` to stop your loop. `Unsubscribing` a `Subscription` is not meant to stop your `foreach` loop. To stop the `foreach` loop simply use `return` or `break`.

Answer (score -3):

Your unsubscribe is inside the subscribe call.. It should be outside as the subscribe call will execute only after you get response from server.

If you want to **unsubscribe** request then you should unsubcribe it outside.

If you want to break the foreach loop then use **return**.

Let me know if you need any futher clarification