# correctly unsubscribe post / put / patch / delete in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

I was wondering what is the best way to unsubscribe a post / put / patch / delete on the HTTP service

for example, given this method, called in a page to save an object:

```
public add(obj) {
const sub = this.service.post('/path/to/resource', obj).subscribe(()=>{
console.log('saved');
sub.unsubscribe();
});
}
```

Do I need to unsubscribe it and did I correctly unsubscribed it?

Updated:
**Please note that this add method will be called multiple times!**

Update 2:
**Yes it is an HttpClient service**

Comment: Have a Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042929/ist-it-necessary-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-created-by-http-methods)

Comment: Is `service` Angular's `HttpClient`? If so, you do **not** have to unsubscribe. It is done for you. See the answer linked by @Vikas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ist it necessary to unsubscribe from observables created by Http methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042929/ist-it-necessary-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-created-by-http-methods)

Comment: There is so much misinformation in the existing answers that this question is doing more harm than good. In the _general_ case you want to explicitly unsubscribe from all `Observable`s. For the `Observable`s returned by Angular's `HttpClient` you do not need to unsubscribe as this is done for you.

Comment: I asked a similar question to this. look at the accepted answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49801713/angular-proper-time-to-unsubscribe

Answer (score 1):

The following will work fine and will not leak subscriptions:

```
public add(obj) {
    this.service.post('/path/to/resource', obj)
        .subscribe(() => {
            console.log('saved');
        });
}
```

Any subscriptions to the `Observable`s returned by `HttpClient`'s methods are automatically unsubscribed. There is no need to do any explicit subscription management here.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to unsubscribe it

Yes, In case your page has multiple HTTP calls, and you want to unsubscribe all calls on routing/page changes etc. then you need to unsubscribe all calls.

> did I correctly unsubscribed it

No, You unsubscribed to HTTP Call immediately after calling, the Best place to unsubscribe HTTP call is `ngOnDestroy` life cycle hook of the component by 
Angular. Like this -

```
ngOnDestroy(){
   sub.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the ngOnDestroy life cycle
const sub;

```
  public add(obj) {
    sub = this.service.post('/path/to/resource', obj).subscribe(()=>{
      console.log('saved');
      sub.unsubscribe();
    });
  }
  ngOnDestroy() { 
        sub.unsubscribe();
  }
```

If you have multiple observables that subscribes then i would suggest to use and subscription array and then destroy it.

```
private subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

public add(obj) {
   subscriptions.push(this.service.post('/path/to/resource', obj).subscribe(()=> 
   {
    console.log('saved');
    sub.unsubscribe();
  }));
}
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscriptions.forEach(subscription => {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
    });
}
```

Comment: Does it really need to `unsubscribe` within the subscribe call as you did in your answer?

Comment: yes, because unnecessary subscribers will lead to memory leaks

Comment: All of this code is completely unnecessary in the case of `HttpClient`

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily should you unsubscribe BUT it is best practice to unsubscribe to prevent memory leaks.

DO SOMETHING LIKE THIS:

```
add(obj){
    this.sub = this.service.post('/path/to/resource', obj).subscribe(()=>{
    console.log('saved');
    });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
   this.sub.unsubscribe()
}
```