# Angular: Should I subscribe() to http.get() each time I need to update?

Tags: angular, observable, subscribe

I wonder if I am using Observable.subscribe() too many times or not.

In my component class, I have a function loadData().
It calls another function this.service.getData() that uses HttpClient.get() to perform a HTTP request to the server.

Currently in my function loadData(), I subscribe to the result of this.service.getData().

Each time the user clicks on a "Update" button, I would like to call my function loadData().

## The question

- If I call my function **loadData()** every time I need to perform HTTP request, will I create as many subscribers?
- Is there a risk of memory leaks?
- If so, do you know how I should refactor my code?

## The answer

- I found this other post [Is it necessary to unsubscribe from observables created by Http methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042929/is-it-necessary-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-created-by-http-methods)
- It explains that the Angular code actually call observable.complete () after an HTTP request, with a delay
- So I modified my code below to check that fact and the tests confirmed that it was true

## Samples of code

```
private loadData() {
    this.loading = true;
     const subscription = this.service.getData()
      .pipe(
  // console.log() with a delay added for test - START
  map(val => {
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      // This will print true.
      console.log('After delay: Is Subscriber closed?', subscription.closed);
    }, 10);
    return val;
  }),
    // console.log() with a delay added for test - END
    takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
        // This will print false.
        console.log('Is Subscriber closed?', subscription.closed);
      },
      error => {
        console.error(error);
        throw error;
      },
      () => {
        this.loading = false;
      });
}
getData(): Observable<DataObject> {
    const uri = encodeURI(this.configService.getUri());
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    if (this.pipelineEtag) {
      headers.set('If-None-Match', this.pipelineEtag);
    }
    return this.http.get(uri, {
      headers: headers,
      observe: 'response'
    }).pipe(
      map(resp => this.processResponse(resp)),
      catchError(error => this.handleError(error, this.envProduction))
    );
}
```

Comment: I believe that http calls create cold observables, which means they indeed create a new subscription for each new value emitted. What you could do is store the subscription `this.x = this.myService.getData().subscribe(...)` and un subscribe manually, or implement a cache system for your requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

each time the HTTP Call returns a value, the Observable completes. so it is safe to do something like this in the Service

```
loadData() { 

    return this.http.get<Data>(dataUrl).pipe(
      //  tap(data => console.log(data)), // eyeball results in the console
      catchError(err => this.handleError(err))
    );

}
```

and then call

```
this.service.loadData().subscribe((data:Data) => do somthing)
```

you can even call exhaustMap or switchMap to control the Observable flow, in order to don't "hint" too many time the server

Comment: Yes thanks for your message. I didn't know about tap. I edited my code to show how I test that subscriber was closed.

Comment: Actually me too doing the similar subscribes multiple times in various components on a centralized data services (data services gets a http data). 
In my case, i am hitting json-server DB to get the JSON data via httpclient. 
What i have noticed is that, whenever subscribe is called either by async pipes or via component code, the json-service db is hit. I can see the json-server terminal updating itself upon every hit. 
So problem right?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct usage, and there is no risk in creating multiple subscribers.

From the documentation:

> The AsyncPipe subscribes (and unsubscribes) for you automatically.

[Source](https://angular.io/guide/http)

---

The technical detail is that once the Http request is completed, the observable's `.complete` method is called which kills all current subscribers. This means that your subscribers are created, used, and the immediately discarded.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So I edited my post because I found on another post that actually Angular make observables automatically complete when making HTTP requests. I read on this page https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#chaining-rxjs-operators that the added value AsyncPipe  is rather to not have to user subscribe() because done automatically

Comment: Actually me too doing the similar subscribes multiple times in various components on a centralized data services (data services gets a http data). In my case, i am hitting json-server DB to get the JSON data via httpclient. What i have noticed is that, whenever subscribe is called either by async pipes or via component code, the json-service db is hit. I can see the json-server terminal updating itself upon every hit. So problem right?

Answer (score 0):

So in the end

- I found this other post : [Is it necessary to unsubscribe from observables created by Http methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042929/is-it-necessary-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-created-by-http-methods)
- It explains that the Angular code actually call observable.complete () after an HTTP request, with a delay
- So I modified my code below to check that fact and the tests
  confirmed that it was true