# How to refactor a subscribe inside a subscribe in rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, rxjs5, rxjs6

For example:

```
this.saveSubscription$ = this.ds.onSave$.subscribe(x => 
  this.sb.updateMachineTool(this.viewEditModel.viewEditModel).subscribe(x = {
    console.log('alert results', x)
  })
)
```

`this.ds.onSave$` is a subject that triggers when a save button on a different component is clicked.

`this.sb.updateMachineTool` is an httpClient post that updates a specific tool

should I be using some type of map so i'm not subscribing to both areas?

How can I refactor this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Refactor your code You can use
[`mergeMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html)
[`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html)

your question is the perfect use case for `switchMap`. because as you have mentioned `this.ds.onSave$` is a subject that triggers when a save button on a different component is clicked.
The advantage `switchMap` gives you in this scenario is it will cancel all the old subscription(Http Call in Progress in your case) automatically if the button is clicked repeatedly.

**ModifiedCode**

```
this.saveSubscription$ = this.ds.onSave$.pipe(switchMap(()=> 
  this.sb.updateMachineTool(this.viewEditModel.viewEditModel)
  )
).subscribe(x = {
    console.log('alert results', x)
  });
```

**For More**

1. [`Understanding mergeMap and switchMap in
   RxJS`](https://netbasal.com/understanding-mergemap-and-switchmap-in-rxjs-13cf9c57c885)
2. [`The Simple Difference Between RxJS switchMap and
   mergeMap`](https://medium.com/@vdsabev/the-simple-difference-between-rxjs-switchmap-and-mergemap-397c311552a5)

Comment: This is awesome and exactly what I needed. As I understand, what's in mergemap will complete itself, I will still need to unsubscribe from `this.saveSubscription$` correct?

Comment: @ghoul Mate `MergeMap` allows for multiple inner subscriptions to be active at a time which is not desirable in your case apart from unsubscribing is considered a good practice.

Comment: I am sorry I meant `switchMap`

Comment: @ghoul https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042929/is-it-necessary-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-created-by-http-methods have a look