# Do Subscription instances without reference handles need to be unsubscribed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, rxjs

Just curious whether `Subscription` instances that are not referenced need to be unsubscribed?  For example [this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/akita-books-store?file=example-app%2Fapp%2Fauth%2Fcontainers%2Flogin-page.component.ts) calls:

```
onSubmit(creds: Creds) {
   this.authService.login(creds).subscribe();
}
```

So each time the someone logs in a `Subscription` instance is created and returned, but there are no handles to it.

IIUC these will just be garbage collected, but figure I'd double check just to be on the safe side.

Comment: yes these need to be captured and unsubscribed inside OnDestroy() method

Comment: So if we don't it creates a memory leak?

Comment: yes, of course, it does

Comment: That's what I figured.  I assume that the `Subscription` instances hold onto a reference to the source observable so they will stay in memory until the source `Observable` instance is either destroyed or `unsubscribe()` is called on it, disconnecting all observers, and presumably the corresponding subscription objects?

Comment: Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51850733/2340159) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41177163/2340159) for more.

Comment: You don't have to unsubscribe to an observable that will complete, but you need to be careful that it completes during the life-cycle of the object that references it. For components, this is before the OnDestroy is called.

Comment: @cgTag In my particular use case I'll be using a `BehaviorSubject`.  So If I call complete() on the `BehaviorSubject` when the application shuts down, then all memory is cleaned up correct?

Comment: Observables do not have to complete. Completing an observable does not prevent memory leaks, but subscribing forever to an observable that never completes creates a memory leak. So it is the subscriber who has to worry about it and not the emitter (i.e. an injectable service).

Comment: You can use DisposeBag to facilitate open subscriptions and disposal:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72055787/1100921

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the Observable completes then there is no need to unsubscribe. Observables created with the http service will complete after calling.

That said it is still best to unsubscribe or have a takeUntil clause.

```
finalise = new Subject<void>();

onSubmit(creds: Creds) {
  this.authService.login(creds).pipe(takeUntil(finalise)).subscribe();
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.finalise.next();
  this.finalise.complete();
}
```

This way you can use the same subject to complete all your Observables instead of managing many subscriptions.

Comment: This has the benefits that it will "cancel" a HTTP request if the component is destroyed before it is finished.

Comment: @cgTag Good Tip!

Comment: You don't have to define the subject as boolean. You can just make it *void*. `finalize = new Subject<void>();` and then `this.finalize.next()`. This will basically emit an *undefined* value.

Comment: So just so I have this branded into my RxJS skills, calling `pipe(takeUntil(finalize)` unsubscribes all the observers when the component is destroyed and also cancels any http requests that may have been started by the source `Observable`?

Comment: It completes the Observable when finalize emits a value. Just make sure your component implements OnDestroy and you emit a value into finalize in the ngOnDestroy.

Comment: Also make sure that the takeUntil clause is the last function in your pipe, putting any other functions like map and filter before.

Comment: Hmmm - Another question - If I create the source `Observable` with a `BehaviorSubject` and have other components that are also listening to the `BehaviorSubject`, will those be disconnected as well when any of the components being multicast to by the `BehaviorSubject` are destroyed?

Comment: It will work for any subscriptions no matter what type of Observable.

Comment: NPM installable operator that encapsulates the logic in the answer.