# How to re-execute subscribed Observable in Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I have a service that fetches a list of users from the API server and caches it:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UsersService {

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}

  users: UsersListInterface[] = null;

  getAll():Observable<UsersListInterface[]> {
    if (this.users !== null) {
      return of(this.users);
    }
    return this.apiService.get<UsersListApiInterface[]>(16, '').pipe(
      map((receivedData: UsersListApiInterface[]) => {
        this.users = receivedData.map(
          function(rawUser: UsersListApiInterface):UsersListInterface {
            return Object.assign({}, rawUser, {
              id: Number(rawUser.id)
            });
          }
        )
        return this.users;
      })
    );
  }

  add(newUser: UserVehicleDongleModel): Observable<string> {
    return this.apiService.post<ResultInterface>(6, 'create', newUser).pipe(
      map((receivedData: ResultInterface) => {
        this.users = null;
        return receivedData.result;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Also, every time there is a new user added, the cache is cleared, so the next time a component requests a list of users, the service will re-query the API server.

I have a component that uses this service and manages a form to add/edit users. In the `onInit` event it subscribes to get all users. It stores the subscription to be able to unsubscribe from it in the `ngOnDestroy` event:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getUsersSubscription = this.usersService.getAll().subscribe(
        ((users) => {
            this.users = users;
        }),
        ((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            console.error(error);
            this.users = [];
        })
    )
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.getUsersSubscription) {
        this.getUsersSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}

onSubmit(add: NgForm) {
    if (add.valid) {
        if (this.selectedUser === null) {
            this.addUserSubscription = this.usersService.add(newUser).subscribe(
                () => {
                    // Refresh list of users?
                },
                (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                    console.error(error);
                }
            );
        } else {
            this.updateUserSubscription = this.usersService.update(newUser).subscribe(
                () => {
                    //
                },
                (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                    console.error(error);
                }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to re-use this subscription to pull the list of users after a new user has been added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all there is no need to manually unsubscribe [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042929/is-it-necessary-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-created-by-http-methods)

Second, create a method and simply call it in your add user subscription.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.refreshUsers();
}

private refreshUsers(): void {
  this.usersService.getAll().subscribe(
        ((users) => {
            this.users = users;
        }),
        ((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            console.error(error);
            this.users = [];
        })
    )
}




onSubmit(add: NgForm) {
    if (add.valid) {
        if (this.selectedUser === null) {
            this.addUserSubscription = this.usersService.add(newUser).subscribe(
                () => {
                    // Refresh list of users?
                    this.refreshUsers();
                },
                (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                    console.error(error);
                }
            );
        } else {
            this.updateUserSubscription = this.usersService.update(newUser).subscribe(
                () => {
                    //
                },
                (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                    console.error(error);
                }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that Ng2 automatically unsubscibes http requests. This is crucial! Thanks!