# Data request from a service does not work

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm retrieving data from a json server using an service, but, when, inside the service i make a `console.log()` the console shows me the data retrieved from the json, but when I try to make it out of the service I get the errors below:

[image]

load-home.service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { API } from '../../app.api'

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'

@Injectable()

export class LoadHomeService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 

  }

  getTarefasInternas(): any {
    return this.http.get(`${API}/getTarefasInternas`)
      .subscribe((response) =>{
        console.log (response) // it works
      } 
  )}

  getTarefasExternas(): any {
    return this.http.get(`${API}/home`)
      .subscribe((response) =>{}
  )}
}
```

home.page.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadHomeService } from './load-home.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage  {
  tarefasInternas : any
  constructor(private homeService: LoadHomeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tarefasInternas = this.homeService.getTarefasInternas()

  }
}
```

Html markup:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let tarefa of tarefasInternas" class="in-list item ion-focusable item-label hydrated">
      <ion-label class="sc-ion-label-ios-h sc-ion-label-ios-s hydrated">
        <h2>{{tarefa.descricao}}</h2>
        <h3>{{tarefa.inicio}} - {{tarefa.fim}}</h3>
        <p>{{tarefa.comentario}}</p>
      </ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

When I call the `console.log` out of the service:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your service method just as below and subscribe in your component,

```
getTarefasInternas(): any {
    return this.http.get(`${API}/getTarefasInternas`)
)}
```

and in component

```
ngOnInit() {
this.homeService.getTarefasInternas().subscribe((data)=>{
    this.tarefasInternas = data;
});
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It Works! But when and how should I Unsubscribe from this service? using the pipe async solves this?

Comment: you can still do it in the component itself

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. When I Change page, for example, the unsubscription is made? I want to prevent memoleaks

Comment: You don't need to unsubscribe from HttpClient observables: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042929/is-it-necessary-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-created-by-http-methods