# How to handle a mid-large result from http request on leaflet map without freezing

Tags: angular, http

I am creating a dashboard with Angular. i'm making a call to Server PostGIS that contains a spatial data to visualize into my leaflet map. 
When i load my page, everything work fine.

The steps are:

- Define a Service that make the request to the server;

```
getDoors(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
      .get(this._endpoint+'/api/doors')
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => console.log('fetched doors')),
        catchError(this.handleError('getDoors')),
        map(this.extractData)
      );
  }
```

- into my component I call:

`this.serverRequest.getDoors().subscribe(res => this.doors = res);`

- to show the results in my template i use  [1]

```
<div *ngIf="doors">        
      <app-map [data]="doors"></app-map>        
</div>

..other template component ..
```

I don't unsubscribe considering we are talking about http calls [2].

As anticipated everything works fine. But considering the large number of result of my query (~5000 results) before showing them on the map pass a few seconds and the page and the other components freezing.

**What would I get?**
I would like my map and my other components to be created and when available, add data.

**Reference**

[1] https://scotch.io/tutorials/3-ways-to-pass-async-data-to-angular-2-child-components

[2] [Is it necessary to unsubscribe from observables created by Http methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042929/is-it-necessary-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-created-by-http-methods)

Comment: This has most likely nothing to do with the async. nature of your http request, but its only related to the mid-large amount of elements being rendered...

Comment: you can check if doors.length is larger the 0 then show data, while that is zero or data is still loading show some loader.

Comment: Thanks for the Feedback