# How to trigger a data service call in Angular

Tags: angular, observable

I have a very simple Angular app - a nav bar, a sidebar and a main area.

[image]

I am using a data service to get the data for the cards in the main area.

Here is the code for the data service:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
// Models
import { Card } from "../models/card";
import { Filter } from "../models/filter";

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ "Content-Type": "applicaiton/json" })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class DataService {
  getCardsUrl: string = "http://ip_address:3000/api/data/cards/";
  getTimeframesUrl: string = "http://ip_address:3000/api/data/timeframe/";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getCardsData(): Observable<Card[]> {
    return this.http.get<Card[]>(this.getCardsUrl);
  }

  getTimeframeFilters(): Observable<Filter[]> {
    return this.http.get<Filter[]>(this.getTimeframesUrl);
  }
}
```

I am subscribing to the data service inside the `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook in main.component.ts.

Here is the code for main.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { DataService } from "../../services/data.service";
import { Card } from "../../models/card";

@Component({
  selector: "app-main",
  templateUrl: "./main.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./main.component.css"]
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  cards: Card[];
  loaded: boolean;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loaded = false;

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.dataService.getCardsData().subscribe(cards => {
        this.cards = cards;
        this.loaded = true;
      });
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```

**Question:**
I want to update the contents of **main** based on the timeframe selection in the sidebar. How do I go about doing this? I am new to Angular, so maybe I am not understanding how Observables work. Can I please have some directions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set an action to the button an call the services again

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { DataService } from "../../services/data.service";
import { Card } from "../../models/card";

@Component({
  selector: "app-main",
  templateUrl: "./main.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./main.component.css"]
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  cards: Card[];
  loaded: boolean;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loaded = false;

    setTimeout(() => {
       this.getCards();
    }, 2000);
  }

  getCards(timeframe?) {
     this.dataService.getCardsData(timeframe).subscribe(cards => {
        this.cards = cards;
        this.loaded = true;
     });
  }

  applyFilter(timeframe) {
      this.getCards(timeframe);
  }
}
```

Add the applyFilter action on the (click) button event with the new value. Maybe the timeframe could be binding with ngModel

Comment: I think this approach will create a new subscription every time the user changes the time. Which is a potential memory leak. `this.dataService.getCardsData(timeframe).pipe(take(1))...` should solve the issue. Or using async pipe in the template.

Comment: @igor_c HttpClient's get how many times emit (without take(1) ) ?

Comment: @igor_c That's not an issue with HttpClient. Angular handles the clean-up automatically. See [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042929/is-it-necessary-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-created-by-http-methods).

Comment: @Rich didn’t know about the HttpClient trick but still a lot of people in that thread write that you should always unsubscribe because user can leave the page thus destroy the component before the request is completed. So I think unsubscribing makes sense and doesn’t hurt even in that scenario.