# How to return a value for a Method in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am mostly a backend dev and am new to typescript and have the following method to return a type

```
PullUserDataFromServer(guid: string): UserDataEntity {
    this.http.get<UserDataEntity>(this.baseUrl + 'api/' + guid).subscribe(result => {
      this.UserData = result;
      console.log(this.UserData);
    }, error => console.error(error));
    console.log(this.UserData);
    return this.UserData;
  }
```

I noticed that this.UserData before returning it remains null and I cant pass the type from the rest call. How can I achieve this?

Comment: async behaviour! you must return `this.http.get<UserDataEntity>(this.baseUrl + 'api/' + guid).subscribe(result => {
      this.UserData = result;
      console.log(this.UserData);  return this.UserData;
    }, error => console.error(error));`

Comment: Got the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You could not return value from a asynchronous function. You can return either a promise or observable of `UserDataEntity`.

### Observale way -

```js
PullUserDataFromServer(guid: string): Observable<UserDataEntity>  {
  return this.http.get<UserDataEntity>(this.baseUrl + "api/" + guid)
  }
}
```

then,

```js
this.PullUserDataFromServer("some-id").subscribe(userData => {
  // some code here.
})
```

### Promise way -

```js
PullUserDataFromServer(guid: string): Promise<UserDataEntity>  {
  return this.http.get<UserDataEntity>(this.baseUrl + "api/" + guid).toPromise();
  }
}
```

then,

```js
const userData = await this.PullUserDataFromServer("some-id");
// use userData in code.
```

Comment: It's not good practice to use promises in Angular. In the angular world you need to start thinking in a reactive way by taking advantage of libraries like Rxjs and the use of streams.

Comment: @PatoVargas Do you have a reference for those good practices you're referring to?

Comment: yep, RxJS you can't be reactive if you don't use streams and if you want to work with streams you need observables, then you can make use of onPush change detection strategy which will help with the performance of you app as well

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to your observable created by the http request. The way I would do it would be like this using RxJS declarative approach. Using methods to call a http request is not wrong but it's the old way of writing Angular Code.

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/blitz-tips-rxjs-pipe-is-not-a-subscribe-125c89437a2c/

In your service:
//This is an Observable

```
pullUserDataFromServer$:Observable<pullUserDataFromServer>;
this.pullUserDataFromServer$ =  this.http.get<UserDataEntity>(this.baseUrl + 'api/' + guid);
```

Whatever component you want to use the Observable;
//Inject the name of your service here via dependency injection

```
    import { ISubscription } from "rxjs/Subscription";
    ....
    private subscription: ISubscription;
    constructor(private nameOfService: NameOfService){}

    this.subscription = this.nameOfService.pullUserDataFromServer$.subscribe(//your code here);

   ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
   }
```

It's important for you to unsubscribe if you subscribe manually to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: There is no need to unsubscribe since http observable is a finite observable and it completes automatically.

Comment: @ArchitGarg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042929/is-it-necessary-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-created-by-http-methods read all the comments and threads, best practice is to unsubscribe unless yo use a rxjs thingy that unsubribes for you like ```take(1)```

Comment: `unless yo use a rxjs thingy that unsubribes for you like take(1)` -> In this case http service is such rxjs thing :)

Comment: Give it a read for best practices - https://netbasal.com/when-to-unsubscribe-in-angular-d61c6b21bad3

Comment: @ArchitGarg did you take a look to the link i sent? they explain there  why you should unsubscribe when using httpClient.

Comment: @ArchitGarg also, httpClient is not part of RxJS. It uses observables from RxJS so it's not the rxjs thingy like you are mentioning