# Angular HttpClient unsubscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Is there a need to unsubscribe from the `Observable` the Angular `HttpClient`'s methods return?

For example:

```
this.http.get(url).subscribe(x => this.doSomething());
```

Do I need to unsubscribe from this subscription? I am asking this is because I don't know if Angular handles it itself. Plus the request is one-off not continuously. I tend to think I don't need to. What are your thoughts?

As per the below post:
[Angular/RxJs When should I unsubscribe from `Subscription`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription)

RxJS handles the one-off subscription but I didn't find anything in their doc.

Comment: Maybe you can check the old question and see if it fits your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042929/is-it-necessary-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-created-by-http-methods

Comment: you don't need to unsubscribe it. It observes until getting a response from api. And once it gets it unsubscribes from the HTTP request you have sent.

Comment: @sibabratswain What if the user navigates away from the current component before the response comes back?

Comment: @RinneHmm Thanks for the link. That is a lot of useful info.

Comment: This should be marked as a duplicate, you have linked to the answer in your question.

Answer (score 14):

No, You don't need to unsubscribe it. It observes until getting a response from api. And once the Http request completes it unsubscribes automatically.

Refer to this

[Why not to unsubscribe Http Observables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042929/is-it-necessary-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-created-by-http-methods)

[Angular guide http](https://angular.io/guide/http)

[AsyncPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

Comment: What if the user navigates away from this component before the response comes back? Do I need the `takeUntil()` pattern?

Comment: Https uses AsyncPipe for the response and the async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the latest value it has emitted. When a new value is emitted, the async pipe marks the component to be checked for changes. When the component gets destroyed, the async pipe unsubscribes automatically to avoid potential memory leaks. So it will automatically unsubscribe if you navigate between components.

Comment: @sibrat swain, `AsyncPipe` is limited to templates as far as I know. Quite often, I need to do complex stuff after I get the data from the server in which case the `AsyncPipe` won't suffice.

Comment: @Antediluvian takeUntil() will work but I guess you don't need it here. Async pipe handles all that for you. That would be a good practice, instead of unsubscribing yourself let the pipe do that everything for you. It will not break your functionalities for complex operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can unsubscribe from all Observables in your page at the 'same' time when your leave the page with ngOnDestroy. You pipe an Observable which is activated when you leave the page and closes the function.

```js
export class X implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private unsubscribe$ = new Subject();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.functionOne();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.unsubscribe$.next();
    this.unsubscribe$.complete();
  }

  functionOne() {
    this.service
      .getData()
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
      .subscribe(
        (result) => {},
        (error) => {}
      );    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to handle this:

1) Yes, you have to unsubscribe manually if you are subscribing to observable normally in the ts file.
usually we can do unsubscribe in the ngOnDestroy() life cycle method

2) If you use async pipe syntax on the observable in angular template, then it automatically close the subscription

```
observable | async
```

Refer below:
https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Comment: He is asking only for `HttpClient` not other `BehaviorSubject`

Comment: I mean if the `Observable` is created by myself, then yes. I need to unsubscribe. But in this particular situation, `HttpClient` creates it for you. And I don't think Angular has got doco on whether I need to unsubscribe.

Comment: It uses async pipe to get the response and the async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the latest value it has emitted. When a new value is emitted, the async pipe marks the component to be checked for changes. When the component gets destroyed, the async pipe unsubscribes automatically to avoid potential memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is necessary to unsubscribe it according to https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-best-way-to-unsubscribe-rxjs-observable-in-the-angular-applications-d8f9aa42f6a0

Here is what I do:

```
export class CustomerSummaryComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  subscriptions: Subscription[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscriptions = [];

    this.subscriptions.push(
        this.customerService.getCustomer(this.customerId).subscribe(
        data => {
        },
        error => {
            console.log(error);
        }
        )
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    for (const x of this.subscriptions) {
      x.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your thought is apparently different from the others. But thanks for the link. I have been reading that article but I don't think it particularly talks about the scenario in question. BTW, I think you can just add all those subscriptions to one parent and unsubscribe from the parent, instead of an unsubscribing loop.