# When we should use unsubscribe()?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have subscribed to many HttpClient requests for posting or getting data.Are these activities memory consuming?Should we unsubscribe them, when we,re done with them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular observables - Do I need unsubscribe if no subscription?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58460256/angular-observables-do-i-need-unsubscribe-if-no-subscription)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042929/is-it-necessary-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-created-by-http-methods

Comment: This link is better https://stackoverflow.com/a/51850733/4711754