# How to unsubscribe from nested observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

Using the ngOnDestroy() method on our Angular component we cancel http requests if they are still pending when leaving a page. On some pages we use a custom generic cache helper to prevent reloading data which are already loaded.

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { AsyncSubject } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class HttpCacheHelper {
    public cache = new Map<string, AsyncSubject<any>>();

    public constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) {        

    }

    public get<T>(url: string): AsyncSubject<T> {
        if (!this.cache.has(url)) {
            const subject = new AsyncSubject<T>();
            this.cache.set(url, subject);
            this.http.get(url)
                .subscribe((data:any) => {
                    subject.next(data as T);
                    subject.complete();
                });
        }
        return this.cache.get(url);
    }
}
```

If I unsubscribe from the AsyncSubject my http call is (of course) not cancelled. How to accomplish that?

Comment: Can't you just use the share operator: http.get<any>().pipe(share())?

Comment: You should consider picking an accepted answer as to help anyone else that might see this post

Answer (score 1):

I this case u dont have to unsubscribe from the http source ( see [this question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042929/is-it-necessary-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-created-by-http-methods). Genarally you could use the take operator or flatmap for nested subscribtions.

Comment: As far as I understand it unsubscribes on completion of the request. In my case I want to unsubscribe on leaving a component.

Comment: why dont u put this.http.get(url) in the cache ?

Comment: The second time I subscribe on the http.get the call is repeated.

Comment: as @Marcel-Hoekstra metioned u can use the share operator

Comment: Does the share operator work with already completed calls? In this case I use it for caching and the cache can be used minutes after the original call is made.

Answer (score 0):

Get the subscription Object and unsubscribe from it.

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { AsyncSubject, Subscription } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class HttpCacheHelper {
    public cache = new Map<string, AsyncSubject<any>>();
    private mySubscription: Subscription;
    public constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) {        

    }

    public get<T>(url: string): AsyncSubject<T> {
        if (!this.cache.has(url)) {
            const subject = new AsyncSubject<T>();
            this.cache.set(url, subject);
    this.mySubscription = this.http.get(url)
                .subscribe((data:any) => {
                    subject.next(data as T);
                    subject.complete();
                });
        }
        return this.cache.get(url);
    }

// Use below function when required
ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.mySubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to unsubscribe from the source:

```
public get<T>(url: string): AsyncSubject<T> {
    if (!this.cache.has(url)) {
        const subject = new AsyncSubject<T>();

        const subscription = this.http.get(url)
            .subscribe((data:any) => {
                subject.next(data as T);
                subject.complete();
            });

         this.cache.set(url, {
           subscribe(observer) { subject.subscribe(observer) },
           unsubscribe(observer) { subscription.unsubscribe() }
         });
    }

    return this.cache.get(url);
}
```

Comment: This looks promising! Which type can I use for the cache map?
new Map<string, ?????>();

Comment: I think it can be Observable<T>

Answer (score 0):

You could try unsubscribing this way as well

Create a subject we want to use to unsubscribe

```
private onDestroy$ = new Subject();
```

Add this before any .subscribe() that you need to unsubscribe from

```
.pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy$))
```

example

```
this.anyService.getData()
  .pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy$))
  .subscribe((data: any) => {
    // Do work ...
  });
```

Then use `ngOnDestroy()` like this

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.onDestroy$.next();
  this.onDestroy$.complete(); // Also unsubscribe from the subject itself
}
```

When we `ngOnDestroy()` runs and we complete the subject any subscriptions using the `takeUntill` will also automatically unsubscribe

Answer (score 0):

I would just go with a `publishReplay` and `refCount`:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpCacheHelper {
  public cache = new Map<string, Observable<yourType>>();

  public constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) {}

  public get<T>(url: string): Observable<T> {
    if (!this.cache.has(url)) {
      const obs = this.http.get(url).pipe(
         publishReplay(1),
         refCount()
      )

      this.cache.set(url, obs); 
    }

    return this.cache.get(url);
  }

  // Use below function when required
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.mySubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```