# Should class variables be initilized before subscribe method or after in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have the method `getAllDates` that appends (inside the `next` handler) all the schedule dates from the server to class scope array variable  `this.futureScheduleDateStrings`. My question is - should I initialize that array to empty content before `subscribe` method or at the beginning of the `next` handler - I have noticed that if I initialize it before `subscribe` it has some duplicates values.

```
getAllDates() {
    this.futureScheduleDateStrings = [];
    this.accountService.getAllDates()
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe({
        next: (value: ScheduleDateTimes) => {
          //this.futureScheduleDateStrings = [];
          this.scheduleDateTime = value.scheduleDateTimes;

          ...
        },
        error: error => {
          console.log();
        }
      });
```

Comment: I don't see how you assign the response data to `futureScheduleDateStrings` here. You mention that there is duplicate data, is it possible that you are appending the data to `futureScheduleDateStrings` and the observable is returned/fired for multiple times? This will result your `futureScheduleDateStrings` contains the value/data from previous Observable.

Comment: I always push never append

Comment: Same. `push` is adding the data into the array, but not re-assign the value. If you want fresh data for each time observable return, you should reset/reassign the array.

Answer (score 0):

You might be experiencing double execution because of the double click on a button that calls `getAllDates` method. Try `debounceTime(300)` to prove it.

Also you don't need `first` if you are working solely with HTTP requests. Observable will [automatically complete after the request is done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60466193/are-http-operations-of-the-httpclient-always-single-value-observables-can-they).

Regarding the initialization of `futureScheduleDateStrings`: you have to initialize it immediately (either with property initializer or in type's constructor). Enable ESLint with recommended rules for your app and you won't need to ask such questions here, it will report all problems in your code immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the problem. Two immediate attempts to call the `subscribe` one after another initialize twice the variable `futureScheduleDates` to empty array.

Then each `subscribe` is called and no initialization is happening anymore - that is why there is duplicate. The only solution I see is to initialize this variable inside the `next` handler.
I don't have anything like mutext like in c#/c++.
Is there any other fix for that problem?

Comment: I am sorry but could you please describe the root of you problem in other words? I didn't understand what you mean by "Two immediate attempts to call the subscribe one after another initialize twice the variable futureScheduleDates to empty array". Obviously `subscribe` is called twice because your method `getAllDates` is called twice. So `subscribe` is not your problem (at least from the code snippet you posted). Also if an array is set to be empty in `subscribe` then it has to be empty because server returned no data.

Comment: "I don't have anything like mutext like in c#/c++" - you don't have "anything like mutext" in JS because it is single-threaded, there is nothing to synchronize.

Comment: Lets say I have three immediate calls to the function `getAllDates()`.
One gets through to the `next` handler of the `subscribe` and two others are stopped at the call to the `this.accountService.getAllDates()` - that is what I see using debugger.
When two calls stop at the call to `this.accountService.getAllDates()` the `futureScheduleDateStrings` is initialized twice to an empty array.
When both of them in a sequence (one after another) get to the handler `next` , the second one will see items that the first one put into the `futureScheduleDateStrings`.

Does this make more sense?

Comment: @Volodymyr Usarskyy Hi Volodymyr - is the question more clear after my last answer?