# Setting the API response in session storage in ngOnInit()

Tags: angular

I want to set one of the user detail that I am fetching from one of the API call in ngOnInit of my component.

But it is setting it as undefined. Although the API get called.

```
ngOnInit() {
 sessionStorage.setItem('Key', this.currentUser());
}

currentUser(){
  this.someService.getData().subscribe((res) =>{
    res.body.name
  })
}
```

I am getting the value undefined in the key when I am trying to access it. 
I am using angular 6.

Comment: The GET call is an asynchronous one. Set the value within the subscription block of the currentUser() and from the ngOnInit() just invoke that method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: tried that . That one is not setting value for the first time .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dealing with asyncronous API call that finishes after ngOnInit.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.currentUser();
}

currentUser(){
  this.someService.getData().pipe(take(1)).subscribe((res) => {
   sessionStorage.setItem('Key', res.body.name)
  })
}
```

Comment: pipe(take(1) ===> what is this for? 
What it does? take(1).

Comment: can normally be skipped off e.g. `this.someService.getData().subscribe(...)` as API calls automatically complete themselves but `take(1)` in case you refactor down the line for multiple outputs from the observable stream. Not unsubscribing is a memory leak. Typical method is a `takeUntil(this.destroyed$)` to prevent subscription running outside component, [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042929/is-it-necessary-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-created-by-http-methods)