# Is it necessary to unsubscribe/complete in a backend service to prevent side effects?

Tags: angular, rxjs, unsubscribe

There has been a lot discussion about when and how to unsubscribe and that subscriptions shouldn't leak outside of a service. I have read many articles about this matter and I think I understood some parts, but what I'm missing in the writeups and tutorials if found, is what to do with the "new subscription pattern" we created.

So I will first explain from which concept I'm talking and put the question afterwards.

---

**CONCEPT:**

*// some.component.ts (extremely simplified)*

```js
this.someSub = this.backendService.someStuff.subscribe(...);

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.someSub.unsubscribe(); // I hope we agree that it is best practice to unsubscribe here, but anyway this is not the question
}
```

*// backend.service.ts*

```js
export class BackendService {
  private _someStuff = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  readonly someStuff = this._someStuff.asObservable();

  constructor(http: HttpClient) { }

  getStuff() {
    this.http.get('...').subscribe( response => this._someStuff.next(response) );

  }
```

---

**QUESTION:**

The above is what I found a good solution from my investigations to not leak the HTTP subscriptions out of the service, but there was also much discussion about the fact that you should unsubscribe form HTTP observables, even though they complete themselves. So I assume this is true for services as well.
But I never saw that the HTTP requests in services were unsubscribed nor were the subjects completed.
Since I expect this is necessary, the following shows the `backenService` how I would expect it should be:

*// backend.service.ts*

```js
export class BackendService implements OnDestroy {                      // A. //
  httpSubs = new Subscription();                                        // B1. //

  private _someStuff = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  readonly someStuff = this._someStuff.asObservable();

  constructor(http: HttpClient) { }

  getStuff() {
    this.httpSubs.add(this.http.get('...')                              // B2. //
      .subscribe( response => this._someStuff.next(response) )
    );     
  }

  // rest of CRUD implementations
  // ...

  ngOnDestroy(): void {                                                               
    this.httpSubs.unsubscribe();                                        // B3. //
    this._someStuff.complete();                                         // C. //
  }
```

I marked things (A.-C.) that are not as I have seen in common tutorials and stuff.
If I don't miss something fundamental about components,services and how missing unsubscriptions might cause side effects... then my questions regarding if unsubscirbe/complete in a service is necessary are:

1. I expect now that we have the subscription in the service, it is mandatory to implement OnDestroy  here (**A.**), as we do in the components to be able to unsubscribe correctly. 
   I guess this is even the case when the service is provided in root (and therfore will destroyed as one  of the last parts of the application), since it might be possible that the service causes side effects on another root service that also isn't garbage collected yet.
   **Is this correct?**
2. If we don't unsubscribe in the servie, we will face the same problems as when we wouldn't unsubscribe in the component. Therefore **B 1 - 3** are added  (in fact the type how to unsubscribe is not important - only the fact we do - I choose the native RxJS approach)
   **Is this correct?**

*(side note: I'm aware that it might be a better approach not to unsubscribe and [handle the side effects manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51850733/6191996) in some cases, but lets ignore this so the question don't gets to broad)*

3. I don't know how `.asObservable` works internally, but there have to be some subscriptions as well.
   **So is it necessary to complete the behaviour subjects (or normal subjects) like `_someStuff` (C.)?**

Comment: I have some remarks. 1. The `BehaviorSubject` is of the type of array of `Stuff`. But it appears you are pushing value of type `Stuff` into it, not an array. 2. `asObservable` does not involve any subscriptions. See [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subject.ts#L142). It just initializes an `Observable` and returns it.

Comment: Thank you for your notes. 1. I edited the examples and removed the types as they seem to be more confusing than helpfull and the question is not about TS types. 2. Tank you for the hint to the implementation, this indeed helps for better understanding.

Comment: Well, I'd say now the `BehaviorSubject` has become redundant. Because we can return the observable from the HTTP directly and unsubscribe in `ngOnDestroy()` hook of the component like you've shown. Nevertheless I am also looking forward to a canonical answer to this question.

Comment: Can you post links to the many articles, writeups and tutorials on this "new subscription pattern" that you've read.

Comment: @Michael D This example is extremely simplified. If we return the HTTP observable directly, this might cause problems. What if mulitple reuqests to `getSuff` are made in the view component or multiple components need it  > this might causes an inconsistent data model on slow networks. The behaviour subject ensures that there is only one truth, because the request don't get directly to the backend.

Comment: @fridoo sure :) I just called it "new subcription pattern" becaue I don't know if there is a common name for this. Also it is usecase specific how exacly you implement the details (e.g. subject vs. behaviour subect and the like) [1.](https://medium.com/@weswhite/angular-behaviorsubject-service-60485ef064fc) [2.](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid/) [3.](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-observable-data-services)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If an observable(e.g: from HttpClient) completes, there is **no need** to unsubscribe.

If the source of the observable **completes** or **emits** an **error**, the source will be **unsubscribed automatically**.

For example, when you have something like this

```js
http.get(...)
 .pipe(
  a(),
  b(),
  c(),
 ).subscribe(observer)
```

A few interesting things happen behind the scenes. First of all the `observer` is converted into a `subscriber`. The `Subscriber` class extends `Subscription`, which is holds the [**unsubscription logic**](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subscription.ts#L53).

Each operator(`a`, `b` and `c`) in the chain there will have its own `Subscriber` instance, because after the first `subscribe`, each observable returned by their operator will be subscribed as well(an operator is a function which receives an observable and returns an observable). What you end up with is a chain of `Subscriber`s.

```js
// S{n} -> Subscriber {n} (in the order in which they are created)
http.get(...)
 .pipe(
  a(), // S4
  b(), // S3
  c(), // S2
 ).subscribe(observer) // S1
```

`S1` is the parent(*destination*) of `S2`, `S2` is the parent of `S3` and so forth.

`HttpClient.get` is essentially the same as

```js
new Observable(subscriber => {
 // Make request

 // On request ready
 subscriber.next(resultOfTheRequest)
 subscriber.complete(); // So here completes!
})
```

[*Source Code*](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/xhr.ts#L208-L219)

What's important to mention is that, in this case, the `subscriber` parameter will be `S4`.

`subscriber.complete()` is the same as `S4.complete()`. When this happens, `S4` will pass along the **complete notification** to `S3`, which will in turn pass along the notification to `S2` and so on until `S1` receives the notification. At this point, it will **unsubscribe**.

When a subscriber **unsubscribes**, all of its descendants will be unsubscribed as well.

So, unsubscribing from a closed subscriber(it becomes `closed` after unsubscribing) is innocuous, but **redundant**.

### 1.

If a service is provided at root level(e.g: `providedIn: 'root'`), its `ngOnDestroy` will not be called. As far as I've noticed, it will be called only if the service is destroyed, which is the case when you provided it at **component level**.

[Here's](https://ng-run.com/edit/7r4rpUZfGxsyfOaepHuI?open=app%2Ffoo.service.ts) a demo which illustrates this.

IMO, if the service is provided at root level, you should not worry about unsubscribing from observables. If, however, your service is provided at component level, you should unsubscribe.

### 2.

As described in the previous sections, if your observables complete, no matter where your service is provided, you should not worry about unsubscribing.

If your observables **do not complete** by themselves(e.g `fromEvent`) and the service is **not provided** at **root level**, you should manually unsubscribe in `ngOnDestroy`.

### 3.

A `Subject` will maintain a list of **active subscribers**. When an active subscriber becomes, well, **inactive**, it will be removed from the subscribers list.

For instance, if you have a `BehaviorSubject` in a root-provided service, you should not worry about throwing away its references.

Actually, a *safer* way to do this would be to call [`Subject.unsubscribe()`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subject.ts#L105-L109). 
`Subject.complete()` will send the complete notification to its subscribers and then will empty out the list.