# is there another way to auto subscribe /unsubscribe to an observable than async pipe?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am wondering if there's another way to auto subscribe/unsubscribe from an observable? I have seen async pipe mostly in html template, but what about when I want to do something in my component class, talking about when you're working in an angular project for example.

Comment: "auto unsubscribe" happens when the observable completes. 
So it depends on your observable. 
Do you have an endles stream, that never completes ? Then you must unsubscribe, or complete it via `pipe(takeWhile(() -> contition)) or pipe(takeUntil(observable)` or just unsubscribing. In case you ask you question because of the "httpClient" Observables, that result from a rest call take a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042929/is-it-necessary-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-created-by-http-methods

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend one of the following unsubscribe methods:

1. [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)
2. Using [`takeUntil`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takeuntil) operator:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private readonly componentDestroyed$ = new Subject();

  ngOnDestroy(): void { this.componentDestroyed$.next() }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    myObservable$.pipe(takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed$)).subscribe(() => {
      // your code here...
    })
  }
}
```

3. Using [subsink](https://github.com/wardbell/subsink) to help you manage subscriptions
4. Using decorator-based approach such as [ngx-auto-unsubscribe](https://github.com/NetanelBasal/ngx-auto-unsubscribe) for angular < 9 or [until-destroy](https://github.com/ngneat/until-destroy) for angular >= 9

Comment: I am using subsink to solve this in my projects, works great.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably create a base class to do so and extend it with your component class, then you don't have to repeat the ngDestory handling for every component that you created.

```
 export class BaseComponent implements OnDestroy {
    public _subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

    addSubscription(...sub): Subscription | Subscription[] {
        this._subscriptions.concat(sub);
        return sub;
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this._subscriptions.forEach(s =>
            s.unsubscribe()
        );
    }
}
```

example usuage

```
class MyComp extends BaseComponent{
    ngOnInit(){
        this.addSubscription(interval(1000).subscribe())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a behavior subject like this

```
    import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
    import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
    import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
    export class ComponentA implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
     private componentUnload$ = new Subject<boolean>();

       constructor(
        public dataService: DataService,
      ) {}


        ngOnInit() {
        this.dataService.items$ // here, you are calling an observable
          .pipe(takeUntil(this.componentUnload$))
          .subscribe(items => {
            this.items = items;
          });
      }

      ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.componentUnload$.next(true);
      }
```