# Why Subscribe is working without Observable in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I wanted to understand some basics of Angular and `HttpClient`. My code is working but I don't understand how. I checked these two links:

1. [How to correctly subscribe Angular HttpClient Observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61353881/how-to-correctly-subscribe-angular-httpclient-observable)
2. [How to declare Return Types for Functions in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736269/how-to-declare-return-types-for-functions-in-typescript)

I've watched this video on YouTube:

1. [observable and subscribe in Angular 8 | Angular 8 Tutorial in Hindi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iZY4roDiqXY&ab_channel=SahosoftSolutions)

I learnt that the syntax of `HttpClient`'s GET method is:
`get(url: string, options: {...}): Observable<any>`

So I did as I was told to do in the video. Here is my case 1:

**UserService**

```
...
export class UserService {
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }
  getAllUsers() {
    return this._http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"):Observable<any>;
  }
}
```

Why VSCode is complaining:

> Value of type 'typeof Observable' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?

In fact my code works perfectly If I don't even specify `Observable` at all. Here is case 2:

```
...
export class UserService {
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }
  getAllUsers() {
    return this._http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
  }
}
```

And here's my component(for both the cases):

**UserList**

```
  users=[];

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {  
    this.fetchAllUsers();  
  }

  fetchAllUsers() {
    this.userService.getAllEUsers().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.users.push(res)
      }
    );    
  }
```

Please point out my mistakes in both cases. I think I'm violating Angular rules somewhere.

PS: Screenshot of the youtube tutorial:

[image]

Comment: `return this._http.get("..."):Observable<any>;` -- this is an invalid syntax. Can you check again what's the actual code?

Comment: @31piy, this tutorial doesn't contains the code. But I've added the screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following line is an invalid statement in your code:

```
return this._http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"):Observable<any>;
```

I think you are trying to specify a return value for the method here, in which case, you need to change the method declaration like this:

```
getAllUsers(): Observable<any> {
  return this._http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
}
```

You might want to take a TypeScript refresher course [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-from-scratch.html).

Comment: I've added the screenshot also in the question. Just now I added. I was told to follow the same.

Comment: And how it works when i dont specify Observable at all anywhere ?

Comment: You'll need to understand the difference between declaration and implementation. The screenshot describes the method declaration. Also, the default return type of http.get is `Observable<any>`, so it doesn't make any difference when you don't add a return type to your method.

Comment: @Tanzeel -- I've added a TS doc link in my answer. You may want to learn more about TS first before jumping on to Angular.

Comment: This was very helpful indeed.