# Is it necessary to unsubscribe the observables in Ionic application?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I'm fetching the data in all pages through various API calls in my application.

Below is what I've been doing in all the pages of my Ionic app.

```
this.homeService.getData().subscribe((response: any) => {
  this.results = response.data;
});
```

I'm making HTTP request, getting response after doing subscription and using that data to display data on views.

Do I need to unsubscribe from all of the observables when I leave the page(s) or route from one page to another? Would it be a performance factor?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35042929/13403499

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it necessary to unsubscribe from observables created by Http methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042929/is-it-necessary-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-created-by-http-methods)