# How to make 2 async calls with rxjs one after the other regardless if the first succeeds or fails

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have a use case where I need to make two async calls. order is important here. The first call needs to complete (or fail) before starting the next call.

I have a example code below showing what I need but it is not done in a reactive way (ie. using rxjs operators)

```
public performDBTasks(): Observable<void> {
    return Observable.create(
    (observer)=> {
        this.performDBTask1().subscribe(
        ()=> {
            this.performDBTask2().subscribe(
            ()=> {
                observer.next();
                observer.complete();
            },
            ()=> {
                observer.error();
            });
        },
        (error)=> {
            this.performDBTask2().subscribe(
            ()=> {
                observer.next();
                observer.complete();
            },
            ()=> {
                observer.error();
            });         
        }); 
    });
}
```

Update: just to clarify the two calls are http like calls so they will return data & complete or error. There will be no stream of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a switchMap and a catchError to both return performDBTask2

```js
const { of, throwError, switchMap, tap, catchError } = rxjs;

const performDBTask1 = () =>
  Math.random() > .5 // 50/50 chance of erroring
    ? of('Success Task 1')
    : throwError('Error Task 1');

const performDBTask2 = () => of('Success Task 2');

performDBTask1().pipe(
  tap({
    next: (val) => { console.log(val); },
    error: (error) => { console.log(error); }
  }),
  catchError(() => performDBTask2()),
  switchMap(() => performDBTask2())
).subscribe((val) => {
  console.log(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.8.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Everytime you hit the `Run code snippet` button above there is a 50/50 chance of performDBTask1 failing but performDBTask2 always succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `from` with `concatMap`, where it will wait until the previous request has finished.

```js
const { from, concatMap, fetch: { fromFetch }, tap } = rxjs;

const endpoints = [
  // Returns 404
  'https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/404-error',
  // Returns 200 
  'https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/1'
];

from(endpoints).pipe(
  // Won't fetch until the previous request has finished.
  concatMap(url => fromFetch(url).pipe(
    tap(url => console.log(`Making request to: ${url.url}`)),
  )),
  tap(resp => console.log(`Code: ${resp.status}`))
).subscribe()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.8.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but I dont see how the second call would work if the first fails.

Comment: Once `fromFetch` completes/fails, the next item in the array will be called.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) and [last](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/last) for your problem.

```js
const { Subject, merge, of} = rxjs;
const { switchMap, last, map, catchError } = rxjs.operators;

const first$ = new Subject();
const second$ = new Subject();

const result$ = first$.pipe(
  // catch an error and return an observable that gets "?" and completes afterwards
  catchError(() => of("?")),
  // only emit if observable completes and return last value
  last(),
  // switch to observable second$
  switchMap((firstValue) =>
    second$.pipe(
      // just for logging purpose - log the first$ and second$ value
      map((secondValue) => [firstValue, secondValue])
    )
  )
);

result$.subscribe(console.log);

first$.next(1);
first$.next(2);
first$.complete();
second$.next(4);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

**Info**

1. *From your question I don't know what exact output you want to achieve. Your qeustions describes only the async call order. If the output does not fit your needs, comment and I can try to adapt. But please keep in mind to specify/udpate your question.*
2. *Your sample code subscribes many subscriptions that are not handled. It is a good practice to avoid as many subscriptions as possible. In perfection you have maximum one subscription for every ui update or backend/service call. Read more in this question about [how to avoid memory leaks with rxjs pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62114244/how-to-avoid-memory-leaks-with-complex-rxjs-pipes-in-angular-9)*
3. *Creating the error via `first$.error("msg")` is not possible. Corresponding stackoverflow question: [How do I throw an error on a behaviour subject and continue the stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41827371/how-do-i-throw-an-error-on-a-behaviour-subject-and-continue-the-stream). Feel free to be simulate an error on the pipe. The simulation is not needed to answer the question so I will avoid implementing a simulation.

Comment: Your solution won't work if the 1st one fails.

Comment: I updated the code so on error we create a new observable that receives a value that can be whatever you want and afterwards completes.

Comment: you can probably simplify to `catchError(() => of('?'))`

Comment: I personally like the `new Observable` more as it is more explizit. But yes that would work aswell. I update the answer for the sake of shorter code :)