# Unsubscribe multiple api subscribe in angular 14

Tags: angular, rxjs6

I'm trying to unsubscribe but it's not working where I'm having one api response inside making another api call.

```
 this.sub = this.dataSevice.gerApp("true").pipe(switchMap(res)=> return this.dataService.getAppTwo("empty")). subscribe((res)=>console.log(res));

ngOnDestroy(){
this.sub.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: If  your observables are created by httpClient, then they will be automatically unsubscribed on completion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042929/is-it-necessary-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-created-by-http-methods

Answer (score 0):

HTTPClient will emit only once. HTTPClient is a finite observable, so it is self completed. No need to worry about unsubscribe.