# Angular App initialization with Observables

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, observable, angular2-observables, injection-tokens

I have this application which needs some initialization before starting.
I'm using the recommended way, with the APP_INITIALIZER, the factory function, etc. along with the syntax in the factory function that allows the use of observables instead of promises.

**init.service.ts**

```
...
constructor(private http: HttpClient){}
...
public init(){
  return this.http.get(url).subscribe((data) => {
    // save data in local variables
  });
}
...
```

**app.module.ts**

```
... 
export function initializeApp(initService: InitService) {
  return () => initService.init(); // this should convert the Obs into a Promise before return
}
...
providers: [
  {
    provider: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: initializeApp,
    deps: [InitService],
    multi; true
  }
]
...
```

Now, this is not working, meaning that the application starts (components rendering  and all)  before the initialization is completed.

As far as I understand the problem is that the function `init()` should return an Observable object. Still, I want the `.subscribe()` part to be defined *inside* the service function.
Is there any way of subscribing to an Observable and returning the Observable object in the same line? (simply prepending a `return` as I did, did not work)

I guess this is the only thing missing, as the provider will ensure that the Promise is resolved before starting the App ?

Thanks for any help,

--Thomas

Answer (score 1):

The `APP_INITIALIZER` expects an `Observable`, so your `InitService` will need to simply map the response data, instead of subscribing.

```
  return this.http.get(url).pipe(map(data) => {
    // save data in local variables
  }));
```

[Here's a working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-goyhqg?file=src/app/init.service.ts) - the `APP_INITIALIZER` in this example will pre-load a random fact about cats into local storage. The `AppComponent` can then read the fact out of local storage on init and display it without having to wait.

Comment: this seems an interesting solution, what's the difference between `.subscribe()` and `.pipe()`? (other that the first returns a Subscriber, while the second returns an Observable). Is `.pipe()` + `map()` solution compliant with the fact that the Observable returned from HttpClient will "autocomplete" after the first event is received?

Comment: The `APP_INITIALIZER` expects either a `Promise` or an `Observable`, which satisfies the interface - a `Subscriber` does not, so yes this is a compliant solution. For your use-case (pre-load some configuration data) it would be expected that the Observable used in `APP_INITIALIZER` would essentially do one thing then be done - in fact, this is exactly how it would work if you were to use a `Promise`, which can only resolve once. It's also a use case described in the Angular documentation on this.

Comment: "it would be expected that the Observable used in APP_INITIALIZER would essentially do one thing then be done"  that's exactly what happens with Observable returned from HttpClient ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042929/is-it-necessary-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-created-by-http-methods ), it sends one message and then complete itself

Answer (score 0):

Apparently a trivial solution to my question is

```
public init(): Observable<any>{
  let obs this.http.get(url);
  obs.subscribe((data) => {
    // save data in local variables
  });
  return obs;
}
```

Probably not fully compliant with Observables best practices, but so far seems to be working.