# Angular intercepted Http subscription not finalize

Tags: angular, rxjs, subscription, angular-http-interceptors

I have an interceptor that check for http response with status code `401` so that it can request `refresh-token` by calling `refreshToken()` before trying the initial request once more.

The `refreshToken()` observe `refreshTokenLockSubject$` so that only one `refresh-token` request can be made, while the others will have to wait for the `refresh-token` request to be completed before trying the initial requests once more.

For instance, let say I have requests `A`, `B`, and `C` that returned status code `401`. Request `A` got to make `refresh-token` request, while `B` and `C` will wait for `A`'s `refresh-token` request to be completed before trying their initial requests once more.

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpHandlerInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  /** unrelated codes **/

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): any {
    /** unrelated codes **/
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError((err) => {
        // handle unauthorized
        if (err.status == 401) return this.refreshToken(req, next, err);
        return throwError(() => err);
      })
    ) as Observable<any>;
  }

  /** Handle refresh token **/
  refreshToken(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler,
    err: any
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.authService.refreshTokenLockSubject$.pipe(
      first(),
      switchMap((lock) => {
        // condition unlocked
        if (!lock) {
          this.authService.lockRefreshTokenSubject();
          return this.authService.refreshToken().pipe(
            switchMap(() => {
              this.authService.unlockRefreshTokenSubject();
              return next.handle(req);
            }),
            catchError((err) => {
              /** unrelated codes **/
              return throwError(() => err);
            })
          );
        // condition locked
        } else {
          return this.authService.refreshTokenLockSubject$.pipe(
            // only unlocked can pass through
            filter((lock) => !lock),
            switchMap(() => {
              return next.handle(req);
            }),
            catchError((err) => {
              /** unrelated codes **/
              return throwError(() => err);
            })
          );
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

The `refreshTokenLockSubject$` is a boolean behavior subject:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  /** unrelated codes **/
  private _refreshTokenLockSubject$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  lockRefreshTokenSubject = () => this._refreshTokenLockSubject$.next(true);
  unlockRefreshTokenSubject = () => this._refreshTokenLockSubject$.next(false);

  get refreshTokenLockSubject$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._refreshTokenLockSubject$.asObservable();
  }

  // requests A, B, and C were constructed similar to this
  refreshToken = (): Observable<any> =>
    this.http.post<any>(
      this.authEndpoint(AUTH_ENDPOINT['refreshToken']),
      {},
      { withCredentials: true }
    );
}
```

Continue with the example above (requests `A`, `B`, and `C`), I noticed that only request `A` `finalize` get called, while requests `B` and `C` were not.

Request `A`:

```
this.companyService
    .A(true)
    .pipe(finalize(() => (this.loading = false)))
    .subscribe({
      next: (res) => { /** unrelated codes **/ },
    });
```

Request `B` and `C`:

```
forkJoin({
  bRes: this.companyService.B(),
  cRes: this.companyService.C()
})
  .pipe(finalize(() => (this.loading = false)))
  .subscribe({
    next: ({ bRes, cRes}) => {
       /** unrelated codes **/
    },
  });
```

Whether requests `B` and `C` are a `forkJoin` does not have an impact as far as I observed.

The `B` and `C` subscription `complete` callback were also not called.

Does anyone know why `finalize` is not called?

Besides that, does this mean the `B` and `C` subscriptions were never unsubscribed?

Comment: `forkJoin()` requires all source Observables to emit at least once and to complete. Do the methods `B()` and `C()` emit a value? Try this in the `forkjoin`:  `bRes: this.companyService.B().pipe(first()),
  cRes: this.companyService.C().pipe(first())` in order to emit at least one value

Comment: @derstauner Interesting. This seems to solve the issue. However, B() and C() are also http observable so they should emit at least once, and they indeed do `next`, Just not `complete` nor `finalize`. Why didn't they?

Comment: Because calling them doesn't simply mean, that they will complete. You have to care yourself of it.

Answer (score 1):

As per definition, `forkjoin` does the following: when all observables complete, it emits the last emitted value from each. The stress is here on `complete`.

One can think, that calling a http get method within forkjoin may be sufficient, but it isn't. The observable has to be completed. This can be done f. e. with the operators `first()` or `take`.

You can f.e. do this:

```
bRes: this.companyService.B().pipe(first()),   
cRes: this.companyService.C().pipe(first())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, this conflict with the [answer by born2net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35043309/7099900) on the question: "Is it necessary to unsubscribe from observables created by Http methods?"

Comment: Furthermore, the forkJoin indeed `complete` whenever the response was not intercepted to make the `refresh-token` request.