# Perfect Way Of Making Http Calls In Angular

Tags: angular, angular-http, observers, rxjs-observables

In the context of the discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/a/35043309/19365092, it is advisable to avoid using the `subscribe` method for HTTP calls. The reason is that while it is true that `subscribe` unsubscribes automatically upon successful API calls, it does not handle errors gracefully. In the event of an API call failure, the observer will remain subscribed, leading to potential memory leaks.

Here's an example of using `subscribe` for reference:

```js
subscribe({
    next: (v) => console.log(v),
    error: (e) => console.error(e),
    complete: () => console.info('complete') // This is only called if the API call was successful
})
```

Instead, it is recommended to use the `firstValueFrom` and `lastValueFrom` methods from RxJS, as they provide robust handling for all scenarios. Both of these methods effectively convert an observer into a promise. Below is an example of how they work:

```js
source.subscribe({
    next: (value) => {
        _value = value;
        _hasValue = true;
    },
    error: reject,
    complete: () => {
        if (_hasValue) {
            resolve(_value);
        } else if (hasConfig) {
            resolve(config!.defaultValue);
        } else {
            reject(new EmptyError());
        }
    },
});
```

This code snippet represents the internal workings of `lastValueFrom`. In the event of an error, it appropriately rejects the promise, ensuring proper error handling.

In summary, it is advisable to use `firstValueFrom` and `lastValueFrom` for HTTP calls when working with RxJS, as they offer better control and handling of both success and error scenarios.

Perfect Way Of Making Http Calls In Angular

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking  . Currently, I don't seem to understand what the question really is. Are you trying to answer your own question? If yes, then formulate the question body to look like a question and put the answer part in the answer section. You are allowed to answer your own question, but don't make the question itself look like an answer.

Comment: I would advise you to edit the question, provide a clear question in accordance with https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , and simply put the part where you solve the problem inside of an answer.

Comment: it is safe to subscribe to http as well as it is safe to convert http calls to promises. memory leaks are more related to long living streams. in http case streams are 99.999% one event and are closed immidiately after that

Comment: @Andrei you are correct, still in case of error in HTTP calls, we need to manually trigger complete, so to avoid this all steps, you better go for lastValueFrom  or firstValueFrom

Comment: in http cases complete triggers automatically after an event. and a surprise is hidden in `lastValueFrom`. it is firing the event when the corresponding observable completes. so it would just not work if http observables didn't ever complete

Comment: also promises does not have a cancel mechanism, so in some rare cases (where cancelling a request is useful) observables are just better

Comment: yes there are many cases, where observables are better