# Handling subscriptions in Angular for API Requests Memory leaks

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, memory-leaks

When I started using Angular, someone in my work place told me to use `take(1)` when performing API calls with [observables](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable) in [RxJs](https://rxjs.dev/), claiming that it automatically unsubscribes after one API call.

So I trusted this claim, and kept using it until I figured out I have massive rendering delays on components load especially when navigating between pages.

Let's take a look at my example:

Here's a `UserRepository` that speaks with the API to grant permissions to the application:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserRepository {

    private apiUrl: string = environment.apiUrl;

    constructor(private readonly httpRequestService: HttpRequestService) {
        super();
    }

    @UnsubscribeOnDestroy()
    getPermissions() {
        return this.httpRequestService.get(`${this.apiUrl}/user/permissions`).pipe(map((res: any) => res.user));
    }
}
```

And the usage:

```
userRepository.getPermissions().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(data => ...);
```

I googled for a bit and figured out that `take(1)` does not automatically unsubscribes and it's not the purpose at all, all it does just takes one observable from the pipe and ignore rest.

##### To fix this I had the following:

1. **Option #1:** Use `takeUntil` with a `unsubscriptionSubject`, call `unsubscriptionSubject.next` to trigger unsubscribe on `ngOnDestroy`
2. **Option #2:** Create an `BaseRepository` with a dictionary of `methodName => Subject`, so for each API call I can save it's own subject, and create a Decorator that automatically unsubscribes from previous API Call, and make sure that there will be never more than one subscription for a type of an API call.

##### Example of the decorator and usages mentioned for Option #2:

BaseRepository

```
export abstract class BaseRepository {
    protected unsubscriptionSubjects: {[key: string]: Subject<void>} = {};
}
```

Implementation:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserRepository extends BaseRepository {

    private apiUrl: string = environment.apiUrl;

    constructor(private readonly httpRequestService: HttpRequestService) {
        super();
    }

    @UnsubscribeOnDestroy()
    getPermissions() {
        return this.httpRequestService.get(`${this.apiUrl}/user/permissions`).pipe(map((res: any) => res.user));
    }
}
```

The decorator:

```
export function UnsubscribeOnDestroy() {
    return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        const originalMethod = descriptor.value;

        descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
            // Access the instance of the class
            const instance = this as any; // Cast to any to access custom properties

            // Create a new Subject for the method
            const methodName = propertyKey;
            instance.unsubscriptionSubjects = instance.unsubscriptionSubjects || {};

            if (instance.unsubscriptionSubjects[methodName]) {
                instance.unsubscriptionSubjects[methodName].next();
            } else {
                instance.unsubscriptionSubjects[methodName] = new Subject();
            }

            // Invoke the original method
            const result = originalMethod.apply(this, args);

            // Return the original result
            return result.pipe(takeUntil(instance.unsubscriptionSubjects[methodName]));
        };

        return descriptor;
    };
}
```

I have went with option #2, and since then everything got fixed, smooth rendering, no delays.

I went with this option because I load a lot of data in the same page without refreshing, so when using it for a few minutes performing a lot of searches, you can see that slowly the loading states become laggy, and everything takes more time to load. So from what I understand the ideal is to always clear the subscription when using it again.

##### I would like to ask:

1. Why doesn't rxjs have built in take only one request and unsubscribe automatically like using `then` and `catch` in axios?
2. Does my approach really fix it or can it cause any other issues that I am not seeing?
3. Why do most frontend developers that use Angular use observables instead of then/catch with axios?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042929/is-it-necessary-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-created-by-http-methods

Comment: `take()` [does actually complete](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/take). But, as stated in the link above, it is not even necessary.

Comment: @BastianBräu I see that it is still necessary on navigating between pages, even if HTTP observable unsubscribes, it does not mean that it will do it when you move between pages which can cause memory leaks. But really, changing all take(1) to takeUntil with a unsubscriber subject in my component (not talking about the decorator i created) and it literally fixed the issues

Comment: the complete callback in an observable subscription does not unsubscribe the subscription. The complete callback is invoked when the observable completes successfully. In contrast, unsubscribing is a separate action that you typically perform to release resources and prevent potential memory leaks.

Comment: You don't need to unsubscribe from an observable that completes, because that's done automatically. This is also described in the mentioned link. Maybe your issue is related to HttpRequestService.

Comment: I use HttpClient of Angular, not sure if its Ng2, I use angular 17 things probably changed. It could be, I am not sure anymore. Everyone says different things on this subject and its mind blowing. One says that take(1) will not unsubscribe but it will complete, one says that completion cancels subscription. But what I am sure of is that changing take(1) to takeUntil with a subject onDestroy fixes all of my performance issues.

Comment: Maybe it could happen because I used outer Observable ForkJoin on two HTTP calls observables and on that forkJoin I added take(1) and since it's an outer observable and doesn't have the auto-clean up like NG2, then this creates a memory leak and in this case I need to do the cleanup myself?

Comment: `forkJoin()` also completes and does not require `take(1)` or unsubscription (unless you want to cancel subscription before it has emitted). I've never heard of or experienced memory leaks from not unsubscribing from a completed observable. Pretty sure this has not changed since earlier versions.

Comment: `httpRequestService.get` can not result in memory leaks, most likely there is problem with its usage. Beware that components may not be destroyed immediately by router, they are cached.

Comment: Using a custom decorator should not be required at all. It’s not clear where your memory leak is coming from.  Can you show some of the usages in your components?  Also, I wonder if your performance issue goes away if you declare a `permissions$` observable with a `.pipe(shareReplay(1))` instead of using `getPermissions()` method that returns a new observable each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. RXJS is an implementation(helper) of reactive programming in javascript.
   In reactive programming you are usually working with an stream of data or events, so the issue emerges when an angular developer uses httpClient or any other modules from angular library which have all accepted the reactive programming paradigm in there code but the rest of the code is not following the same paradigm.
   so your first question answer would be if RXJS worked like that what would be the purpose of RXJS or the angular httpClient module just use fetch directly.
2. I think your approach is not a good one because it hasn't been designed in the mindset of reactive programming. A hint to what you are doing wrong is that you think the consumer of the getPermissions() function or any other function which you want to use the decorator with will always subscribe once and doesn't want the observable anymore. you can have multiple subscriptions to the same observable.
3. The answer to your final question can be concluded from the above. as an angular developer you have accepted to implement your application according to reactive programming paradigm angular works best when you use it like that so httpClient module of angular is best suited for the job.

Comment: Yes but in my case, the endpoint that has this decorator is used by one consumer at a time, the ones that do need to be reactive does not use that decorator. Everything is done on demand, I dont think that the whole system has to be "reactive", there are some functions that are used by one consumer and only update data in one location. For example a dedicated request for specific page load that should not affect any other area in the app except itself.

Comment: I think you are doing so much extra work, why don't you use async pipe with the observable and be done with it.
the way you are solving it is interesting, but in the end it is an anti pattern and in future it can cause issue. what if a month later you want to use the `getPermissions()` method someplace else which is not like this one. what happens if you want to use UserRepository not as a singleton.

Comment: Oh async pipe... 4 years with angular and never thought of looking into what is the point of using them in the template. Thanks ill take a look. I completely understand your point, its better to follow the pattern to prevent further issues and allow repositories to be scalable for future different uses

Answer (score 5):

The cleanest way to ensure that a subscription is unsubscribed is to use the newly availalbe `destroyRef` in conjunction with `takeUntilDestroyed`

```js
   import { DestroyRef } from '@angular/core';
   import { takeUntilDestroyed } from '@angular/core/rxjs-interop';

    export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    private destroy = inject(DestroyRef);

    constructor() {
        this.user$
            .pipe(takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroy))
            .subscribe((aUser: User | null) => {
                this.currentUser = aUser;
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why doesn't rxjs have built in take only one request and unsubscribe automatically like using then and catch in axios?

Some observables "finalize" themselves, while others need to be finalized from the outside. HttpClient's get method, for example, completes immediately after response returns.

> Does my approach really fix it or can it cause any other issues that I am not seeing?

Decorators are great, but they should be carefully designed. For example, your implementation involves a dictionary, which must assure that its values are never overwritten. Second, if you modify your decorated method to return a non-Observable type, your decorator will throw an error.

Now, consider self-completion of HttpClient.get(...) discussed earlier. Using rxjs operators such as take(1) to apply completion is not necessary in this case. With your example, however, there is one more point to clarify. You choose to wrap http with a repository class, meaning you abstract away the use of http. So apparently no guarantee that some day someone decides to replace underlying implementation (http) with something that returns a never-ending stream observable - in which case an rxjs operator will be required!

Fortunately, we are discussing in terms of design. The nature of a repository object, especially for query purposes, is to return a single-emission, self-completing observable. We are not expecting an open, continuous stream to be produced by a storage-query. So leaving getPermissions with no rxjs operator such as take(1), is OK by design IMHO.

> Why do most frontend developers that use Angular use observables instead of then/catch with axios?

Observables express the concept of reactive programming, in contrast to promise-based programming. Moreover, observables express streaming concepts, which are perceived by many developers to be more convenient to handle than promises.

Answer (score 1):

For your question 2. Your solution is very good and we have to do that.
We know the HTTP request (using HttpClient) is automatically complete (because the HTTP request is emitted only once and then completed)

So almost all developers say don't need to unsubscribe/ or don't need to add take(1).

However, if the HTTP request takes a long time to finish. Your approach is good. It helps us unsubscribe the HTTP request before it is complete.

[Check Example in User component](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angualar-routing-in-angular-demo-example-szurmh?file=src%2Fapp%2FrouteFiles%2Fusers%2Fusers.component.ts)

Navigate to /users, then leave after 5s.
As you can see after leaving the User component 10s. The messages `Http 2 Response` & `Execute logic when HTTP 2  response`  are still written to the Console.

With my experience. I suggest we should always unsubscribe to void unexpected side effects

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').subscribe({
      next: (res) => {
        console.log('Http 1 Response ', res);
      },
      complete: () => {
        console.log('Http 1 complete ');
      },
    });

    this.http
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .pipe(delay(10000))
      .subscribe({
        next: (res) => {
          console.log('Http 2 Response ', res);
          console.log('Execute logic when http 2  response ');
        },
        complete: () => {
          console.log('Http 2 complete ');
        },
      });

    this.http
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .pipe(delay(10000), takeUntil(this.destroyed$))
      .subscribe({
        next: (res) => {
          console.log('Http 3 Response ', res);
          console.log('Execute logic when HTTP 3  response ');
        },
        complete: () => {
          console.log('Http 3 complete ');
        },
      });
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to wrap your HTTP request to [firstValueFrom](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/firstValueFrom), thus converting it to **Promise**? You won't need to **subscribe()** in this case.