# Angular - Remove object from memory without destroy component

Tags: angular, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, components

I have an quite complex angular app and it causes the browser to crash very quickly. So I am looking to optimize it. I fix every subscription memory leak but the problem is still here. So I use Chrome debug module to try to find the problem. In Memory tab, I do rec session to find whats is going wrong. First I only activate few things to understand.

I have one component which never destroy and every click on menu call refreshWrapper() function:

```
refreshWrapper() {
    // RESET
    this.appS.structure.reset(this.type, this.wrapper, this.appS.navigationS.navigations[this.type + '.' + this.wrapper].step);
    // GET GRID
    this.appS.restS.post('grid/elements', { route: this.route }).subscribe(response => {
            this.appS.structure.displayeds[this.type + '.' + this.wrapper] = new SiteModule(response.displayed);
    });
}
```

Here is my Structure Model reset function, I try to clear variable:

```
reset(type: string, wrapper: string, step: string) {
     delete this.displayeds[type + '.' + wrapper];
}
```

See my SiteModule Class constructor:

```
constructor(datas ?) {
Object.assign(this, datas);
// GRIDS
if (datas?.grids) {
  this.grids = [];
  datas.grids.forEach(grid => {
    this.grids.push(new Grid(grid));
  });
}
```

}

In Grid Class

```
constructor(datas ?, element ?: Element) {
Object.assign(this, datas);
// BLOCS
if (datas?.blocs) {
  this.blocs = [];
  datas.blocs.forEach(bloc => {
    this.blocs.push(new GridBloc(bloc, element));
  });
}
```

}

GridBloc Class

```
constructor(datas ?, element ?: Element) {
Object.assign(this, datas);
// ELEMENTS
if (datas?.elements) {
  this.elements = [];
  datas.elements.forEach(e => {
    this.elements.push(new Element(e, element));
  });
}
```

}

Element Class

```
constructor(datas ?, element ?: Element) {
Object.assign(this, datas);
// DETAILS
if (datas?.details) {
  this.details = [];
  datas.details.forEach(detail => {
    this.details.push(new Detail(detail, this.ressource_id));
  });
}
```

}

In Chrome Memory tab, I see that there is well only one SiteModule Object. But it keep linked object, ie I got lots of Element Object (it keep old one even when I click on menu so when refreshWrapper function is called).

Here a screen of memory tabs to show Element Class (the first one referenced to element.model.ts:61 is the good one) but all the other are old ones. Whats "[10] dans (GC roots) @3" for the old ones means ?

[image]

I don't understand why. I think it's garbage collector problem because I don"t detroy the component and I store variable in global service (AppS here) but how to fix this ? Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

> I fix every subscription memory leak but the problem is still here.

In the given code there is already a memory leak visible.

```
// GET GRID
this.appS.restS.post('grid/elements', { route: this.route })
  .subscribe(response => {
    this.appS.structure.displayeds[this.type + '.' + this.wrapper] = new SiteModule(response.displayed);
  });
```

This is a subscription without an unsubscription. I have no idea how often your  `refreshWrapper` function is called, but with every call you add one subscription to your memory.

As a solution I recommend to pipe the `first` or `take(1)` operator.

```
// GET GRID
this.appS.restS.post('grid/elements', { route: this.route })
  .pipe(
    first(),
  ).subscribe(response => {
    this.appS.structure.displayeds[this.type + '.' + this.wrapper] = new SiteModule(response.displayed);
  });
```

Comment: In fact, I check this subscription with .closed into a timeout and it was well closed automatically. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042929/is-it-necessary-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-created-by-http-methods