# subscribe in Angular 2

Tags: angular, subscribe

I want my ngOnInit function do next things:
 - make http request for some data using this.structureRequest.sendRequest(),which works fine,  and after data have been received to start view it using this.viewNodes() function.
I use subscribe , but it does not work, I think I do something wrong with subscribe function. please help:)

1. HomeComponent.ts

   ```
   import {Component} from '@angular/core';
   import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
   import {StructureRequestService} from './StructureRequestService';


   export class Content {


   ok: boolean;
   content = [];
   }
   @Component({
   providers: [StructureRequestService],
   styleUrls: ['app/home/home.css'],
   templateUrl:'./app/home/homePageTemplate.html'

   })

   export class HomeComponent {
   contentArray = [];
   myRes: Content;
   showAssigned:boolean = false;
   showSubitems:boolean = false;
   showUsers:boolean = false;

   constructor(private structureRequest: StructureRequestService) {}

   ngOnInit() {
   this.structureRequest.sendRequest().subscribe( this.viewNodes());

   }

   viewNodes() {
   this.myRes = this.structureRequest.result;
   this.contentArray = this.myRes.content;
   this.showAssigned = true;
    }
    }
   ```

2.Here is http service, http get works fine, all data received:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';

import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable ()
export class StructureRequestService {
result: Object;
//private myUrl = 'http://manny.herokuapp.com/audit/get/structure';
private myUrl = './app/home/nodes.json';  // local URL to structure APi
constructor (private http: Http) {
    //use XHR object
    let _build = (<any> http)._backend._browserXHR.build;
    (<any> http)._backend._browserXHR.build = () => {
        let _xhr =  _build();
        _xhr.withCredentials = true;
        return _xhr;
    };
}

sendRequest() {
    let body = JSON.stringify({});
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({
        headers: headers
    });
     this.http.get(this.myUrl, options)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .subscribe(res => {this.result = res;
            return this.result; });
}
}
```

3.so the problem is to make synchronous steps: receive data, than view it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to subscribe to an event on a service in angular2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31131490/how-to-subscribe-to-an-event-on-a-service-in-angular2)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably want to execute `this.viewNodes` when the request returns a value and not execute the result of `this.viewNodes()`

This

```
this.structureRequest.sendRequest().subscribe( this.viewNodes());
```

should be changed to

```
this.structureRequest.sendRequest().subscribe(() => this.viewNodes());
```

The former executs `this.viewNodes()` and passes the result to `subscribe()`, the later creates a new inline function which is passed to `subscribe()`. This inline function, when called, executes `this.viewNodes()`

If you want to pass the value `sendRequest()` returns it should be

```
this.structureRequest.sendRequest().subscribe((result) => this.viewNodes(result));
```

**update**

`sendReqeust()` doesn't return anything.

It should be

```
return this.http.get(this.myUrl, options) ...
```

but this only works the way you use it in your code if it returns an `Observable`.

but the `subscribe()` at the end returns a `Subscription`

```
 return this.http.get(this.myUrl, options)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .subscribe(res => {this.result = res;
        return this.result; });
```

therefore this should be changed to

```
 return this.http.get(this.myUrl, options)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .map(res => {
      this.result = res;
      return this.result; 
    });
```

or

```
 return this.http.get(this.myUrl, options)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .do(res => {
      this.result = res;
    });
```

The difference is that `do()` doesn't modify the value of the stream and doesn't need to return anything. The value returned from `.map()` will be forwarded. Ensure `do` is imported (like `map`) if you want to use it.

Comment: I've tried
     this.structureRequest.sendRequest().subscribe((result) => this.viewNodes(result));

but this.viewNodes does not starts

Comment: super.works! thank you for very good explanation. I've marked your answer.

Comment: as always, gunter replies here on stack overflow are helping alot of folks doing some angular stuff