# Use of EventEmitter in service of Angular6

Tags: rxjs, angular6, angular2-observables, eventemitter, subject

> Why Event Emitter can't use in service in angular 6?

In [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) they mentioned, "Use in directives and components to emit custom events"

Comment: EventEmitter is supposed to be used only for `@Output`, which services cannot have. You're not supposed to manually subscribe to emitters, it's for template bindings only.

Answer (score 0):

Because in services all waht you have to do is manipulating data, if you want to notify the data changes you can use `Subjet` or `BehaviorSubjet`. EventEmitter is generally used to notify changes from child to parent and as said is supposed to be used only for `@Output`.

please take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31131490/how-to-subscribe-to-an-event-on-a-service-in-angular2)