# When to use @output over Subject?

Tags: angular

Consider two component `c1, c2`. I want to transfer some data from `c1` to `c2`.
One way I could do it is to create an `EventEmitter` with `@output` in `c1` and `.emit()` when need to. Then `.subscribe()` it at `c2` and get the data.

As far as I know using `rxjs::Subject` is better than using `EventEmitter` because the last expands the `rxjs::Subject`. So why would I use `@output EventEmitter` at all? I could always just use `rxjs::Subject`..

In which circumstances I would use `@output EventEmitter` variable?

**My Guess**:
Two cases:
1. Using services: Using `Subject` instead of `EventEmitter` due runtime performance.
2. not Using services: Then **I have** to declare `@output`. Then, when using `@output`, `EventEmitter` is necessary to use. Then use `EventEmitter` over `Subject`.

Comment: Instruction is unclear. What are relations between those component? Are they siblings? Or maybe a parent with a child? How will access rxjs Subject from one component in another component? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @Ivan It is unclear on purpose. Because this is the question. In which cases, I would use `@output` over `Subject`?

Comment: @Zircon No. It is not the same Q. The referenced question is about using EventEmitter against subject *only when @output* is involved.

Comment: @QwertTrewq Sorry, I don't follow. You should only use `EventEmitter` when you're using `@Output`, and when using `@Output` you should always use `EventEmitter`. Details about this and the advantages of `EventEmitter` in this case are detailed among answers in the linked question.

Comment: @Zircon Yes, you are right. But as known, `subject` is better, in aspects of runtime, than `eventEmitter`. **So why would I use `@output` instead of `subject` from the start?**

Comment: @QwertTrewq I recommend looking at the dupe question and its linked reference. The main benefits: `EventEmitter` is a `Subject` that is automatically closed by Angular while also having functions that help ensure the dev does not misuse it.

Comment: @Zircon I edited my Q.

Comment: @QwertTrewq Thanks, I think I understand your question. Check out this answer for when to use `EventEmitter` https://stackoverflow.com/a/52127045/4793951 (summarized: Child to parent only). For the Angular way to handle all types of component interaction check out the official guide: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction (each use case varies based on the relationship between components)

Comment: @QwertTrewq and still... it's very clear how you can use EventEmitter. But there is no clear way you can use just a subject you need a service for it. You updated you question and now it's pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

> Consider two component c1, c2. I want to transfer some data from c1 to c2. One way I could do it is to create an EventEmitter with @output in c1 and .emit() when need to. Then .subscribe() it at c2 and get the data.

It's not the typical use of outputs in Angular. Usually you'll have a parent component consuming its child's output, like this:

```
<app-child-component (click)="handleClick($event)"></app-child-component>
```

Or, maybe a more complex case:

```
<app-child-component *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" [someParameter]="item.name" (click)="handleClick($event, i)"></app-child-component>

...

handleClick = (what: Item, whichOne: number) => { //...
```

Doing the same with subjects, explicit subscriptions, explicit cleanup, *should be* doable, but would probably result in longer, uglier code.

Comment: But in other aspect, run time of application would be better with `Subject` than `@output eventEmitter` because of the fact that `eventEmitter` expands `Subject`. So - is it all about uglier code VS run time considerations?

Comment: Can you provide actual benchmarks to confirm the performance loss? How significant is it?

Comment: Well, `eventEmitter` expands `Subject`.. So why wouldn't it be performance loss?

Comment: Because it transpiles to the same thing anyway? I don't know. I haven't tested it. Have you? The point is: assuming that you lose performance simply because the `extends` keyword appears in the source code is unwarranted.

Comment: I think I found where I was wrong. I forgot that, in case you don't use service - **You have to declare an `@output` to transform the data to `c2`**. So basically always use `Subject` when Using Services?

Answer (score -1):

Why do you say `Subject` is better than `EventEmitter`? `EventEmitter` is a subject that can emit synchronously or asynchronously the message....

It looks better to use `EventEmitter` with `@output`... Otherwise, you have to have a reference of your emitter on the parent... then subscribe manually to it...

`(emitter)="doSomething($event)"` looks more simple and elegant